# Error "member function redeclaration not allowed" with boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I have this problem with `boost::thread` that i cannot solve.

I have a `classX.h` file:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
class classX{

    ...
    void startWork(void);
    void doWork(void);
    ...

}
```

and then a `.cpp` file:

```
...
void classX::startWork(){
boost::thread(&doWork);
}
void classX::doWork(){
...
}
```

I cannot compile, i obtein the error (at the line in which i do `boost::thread(&doWork)`):

```
error C2761: 'void plsa_mt_2::doWork(void)' : member function redeclaration not allowed
```

Is this error related with the thread creation or with something else? What can i do to solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `classX::doWork()` is a member function of `classX`, you can't call the member function pointer `(&classX::doWork)` without providing a pointer to a `classX`.

The Boostiest way to accomplish this is by using Boost Bind to create a callable functor with the member function pointer and a pointer to the classX, like so:

```
void classX::startWork() {
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&classX::doWork, this)); // be careful, the boost::thread will be destroyed when this function returns
}
```

You could alternatively make `doWork()` a static member function or a global function if `doWork()` doesn't need access to instance properties of the `classX`:

Answer (score 1):

firstly, the correct syntax for getting a pointer to a member function is

```
&classX::doWork
```

However I tink you might not be showing the exact code yielding the error, because the typical error for `&doWork` in VS is

```
error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression
```

Comment: You are right about about `&classX::doWork`. About the error i'm not really sure, but i solved passing `boost::bind(&classX::doWork, this)` as argument.