# std::thread calling method of class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

I have a small class:

```
class Test
{
public:
  void runMultiThread();
private:
  int calculate(int from, int to);
}
```

How its possible to run method `calculate` with two differents set of parametrs(for example `calculate(0,10)`, `calculate(11,20)`) in two threads from method `runMultiThread()`?

PS Thanks I have forgotten that I need pass `this`, as parameter.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Not so hard:

```
#include <thread>

void Test::runMultiThread()
{
    std::thread t1(&Test::calculate, this,  0, 10);
    std::thread t2(&Test::calculate, this, 11, 20);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

If the result of the computation is still needed, use a *future* instead:

```
#include <future>

void Test::runMultiThread()
{
     auto f1 = std::async(&Test::calculate, this,  0, 10);
     auto f2 = std::async(&Test::calculate, this, 11, 20);

     auto res1 = f1.get();
     auto res2 = f2.get();
}
```

Comment: All sorts of problems with this.  Why the upvotes?  The return value is discarded unchecked.  Presumably the calculate method iterates over something - is it thread safe?

Comment: @ravenspoint: Whether it's threadsafe is up to the OP, non? I agree that the return value should be recovered, though the OP doesn't indicate that that's intended (it could be like `printf`). `std::async` would be an alternative.

Comment: That's why I asked the OP what problem he found, instead of slapping down a half-answer that might will end up giving the OP even more grief.

Comment: Why spawn two new threads and then block the current thread? Usually better to spawn one new thread and do the other calculation in the current thread.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Maybe because the OP asked so? Though we don't know if his approach is correct in the first place, but maybe he does other computations meanwhile.

Comment: No, the OP said "in two threads" not "in two new threads". The current thread could be one of the two.

Comment: This answer has, so far, received 6 upvotes.  It is impossible to know what OP's problem was, so how can all these people imagine the answer is useful?

Comment: @ravenspoint: The question asked how to run a function in different threads with different arguments, and this answer clearly demonstrates how to do that. How is that not useful?

Comment: @ravenspoint: From OP's description of the problem, it is almost clear what he wants: he wants to run the function `calculate` in two different threads passing two different sets of arguments (also, it is likely that he wants to create two *new* different threads).

Comment: @Nawaz  the original question is not at all clear.  Does he need to check or store the return value from calculate().  Does the calculate() function have any side effects?  Are all objects touched by calculate() thread-safe?  There are always many 'gotchas' designing multithreaded applications.  To say that it is 'not so hard' is very misleading.

Comment: @ravenspoint: Those are *other* questions; and there can *more other* questions as well.

Comment: I didn't think that the number of threads would be a point of contention. I'm merely demonstrating the techniques; I'm confident the OP can arrange the code in any fashion that suits her ultimate concurrency needs.

Comment: This was helpful to me, but why does this need to be passed aside for the fact it is required to not have an error? :)

Comment: My problem with this answer is that when I am trying the snippet, the object of Test class is being destroyed when std::thread starts. This is under GCC 5.3, not sure of other implementations.