# Futures vs. Promises

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, future

I'm confusing myself with difference between a future and a promise.

Obviously, they have different methods and stuff, but what is the actual use case?

Is it?:

- when I'm managing some async task, I use future to get the value "in future"
- when I'm the async task, I use promise as the return type to allow the user get a future from my promise

Comment: I wrote a bit about this [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12335206/596781).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is std::promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004273/what-is-stdpromise)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Future and Promise are the two separate sides of an asynchronous operation.

`std::promise` is used by the "producer/writer" of the asynchronous operation.

`std::future` is used by the "consumer/reader" of the asynchronous operation.

The reason it is separated into these two separate "interfaces" is to **hide** the "write/set" functionality from the "consumer/reader".

```
auto promise = std::promise<std::string>();

auto producer = std::thread([&]
{
    promise.set_value("Hello World");
});

auto future = promise.get_future();

auto consumer = std::thread([&]
{
    std::cout << future.get();
});

producer.join();
consumer.join();
```

One (incomplete) way to implement std::async using std::promise could be:

```
template<typename F>
auto async(F&& func) -> std::future<decltype(func())>
{
    typedef decltype(func()) result_type;

    auto promise = std::promise<result_type>();
    auto future  = promise.get_future();

    std::thread(std::bind([=](std::promise<result_type>& promise)
    {
        try
        {
            promise.set_value(func()); // Note: Will not work with std::promise<void>. Needs some meta-template programming which is out of scope for this question.
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            promise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
        }
    }, std::move(promise))).detach();

    return std::move(future);
}
```

Using `std::packaged_task` which is a helper (i.e. it basically does what we were doing above) around `std::promise` you could do the following which is more complete and possibly faster:

```
template<typename F>
auto async(F&& func) -> std::future<decltype(func())>
{
    auto task   = std::packaged_task<decltype(func())()>(std::forward<F>(func));
    auto future = task.get_future();

    std::thread(std::move(task)).detach();

    return std::move(future);
}
```

Note that this is slightly different from `std::async` where the returned `std::future` will when destructed actually block until the thread is finished.

Comment: @taras suggests that returning `std::move(something)` is useless and it also hurts (N)RVO. Reverting his edit.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 please use std::cout << future.get().c_str();

Comment: For those who are still confused, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004273/what-is-stdpromise/12335206#12335206).

Comment: That is a one time producer - consumer, IMHO that is not really a producer - consumer pattern.

Comment: What does  '&' signifies in statement 'auto producer = std::thread([&]'

Comment: @NileshShinde: capture everything in the enclosing scope by reference.