# Passing data to function from different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have long-running function in my C++ 11 application that is essentially `sub_main`. I need to inform this function about `situation` risen in different thread. Requirements:

- The `situation` can be risen at any time
- The application should handle the `situation` at most at single place (it can leave it unhandled as well)
- It does *not* need to be ultra fast nor not-delayed in execution

As of now I considered two option:

1. Pass object factory with factoree that contain internal queue of `situations`. The object is then polled at regular interval inside `sub_main` for new `situations`. Polled object is removed from queue. When application decide it will not handle the situation in particular place, it can move it back to global `situations` queue and next constructed factoree will get the `situation` (so it can be handled elsewhere in `sub_main`)
2. Analogous situation, but instead of polling, use lambda function that updates local variable inside `sub_main` as needed. This version does not use continous polling, but is less readable

Both seems a bit complicated and I am wondering if I missed a more simple solution. The problem is the `sub_main` is being implemented outside of my library and I am providing end-user with my `situations`

Comment: You could use a variable and a mutex?

Comment: @JakeFreeman Which variable? Global variable? Passed variable? Which type?

Comment: To clarify a global variable @piotrK

Comment: @JakeFreeman Global variables are really awful for that sort of things... imagine my client request I have more than one `sub_main` running at the same time (which is actually likely in this kind of project)

Comment: You might want to look at the [Chain-of-responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Comment: @PhilBrubaker Thats a nice lead, I missed that one!

Comment: As asked, this has very little to do with C++, but is a basic inter-thread communication design. The standard C++ library does not provide thread-safe containers (like a queue) for passing work around. You can roll your own, or pick one that is already written (and probably more mature than what you will write). [RecursionSW](http://recursionsoftwareinc.com/) and [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) are just two that I'm familiar with. On a more primitive level are things like Posix semaphores and condition variables.

Comment: You may be describing the interaction of `std::promise` and `std::future`.

Comment: @jwm I've already have simple concurrent queue based on different (not-mine) stack overflow question. But the question itself is inside C++ domain, so any solution that utilize STL/Boost/whatever 11 has offered is preffered

Comment: @DrewDormann Can you elaborate a bit more...?

Comment: @PiotrK can you comment as to whether [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620186) solves your problem?  A promise, in any thread, would produce a `situation`.  While a future, in any thread, could detect and receive that `situation`.

Comment: I would refrain from global variables.  They get messy if you have multiple threads that affect the same variable.  What i do is pass a callback function to each thread and use that as a notification gateway from the threads back to the caller.

Comment: @DrewDormann Is it only single-time working? There can be (and will be) more than one `situation` to be handled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using suggestion of @PhilBrubaker and Chain of Responsibility:

```
void sub_main(std::shared_ptr<situation_register> situation_register)
{

    std::unique_ptr<handler_instance> instance =
        situation_register->register(priority::main, [=](situation* s)
        {
            switch(s->get_type())
            {
                 case situation::screensaver:
                      s->get<situation_screensaver>()->prevent();
                      s->mark_as_handled();
                 break;
            }
        });


}
```

In this case, if function does NOT explicit says the `situation` was handled it will be passed to next registered handler (they are sorted based on `priority`). The `handler_instance` is lightweight object that will deregister handler in its destructor.