# How to run line of codes asynchronously in c++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, gtk

I want to run some bunch of codes asynchronously in c++. This is for an gtk GUI application. I want to get the length from a encoder to an variable while running the other parts of the code. This lines of code should be always running. When i want the length, i should be able to get the current length from the variable. Can any one help me on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use std::async vs std::threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814365/when-to-use-stdasync-vs-stdthreads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't understood what exactly you want to do. But I think you can read more about the [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

void asyncFunction ()
{
    std::cout << "I am inside async function\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::future<void> fn = std::async(std::launch::async, asyncFunction);
    // here some other main thread operations
    return 0;
}
```

Function that is run asynchronously can also return a value, which can be accessed through the future with `std::future::get` blocking method.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer because all the problems with notifying the run loop is still left out and thats also the most important part.