# how to destroy a thread explicitly created by std::thread?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I want both the threads to run in infinite loop initially, but after sometime i want to kill the first thread without waiting for it to complete, and the second should run normally. How can i implement it?
When i run the below code, it gives debug error!

```
void f1(int i)
{
    while (1)
     {
             printf("Executng Thread  %d : %d\n", i, j);
            Sleep(10);
    }

}


int main()
{   
    std::thread t1(f1, 1);  
    std::thread t2(f1, 2);

    Sleep(100);
     t1.~thread();  
    while (1)
    {

        Sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can implement "just killing something" by pulling the plug from your computer. If you want to be able to reason deterministically about the behaviour of your program, then you need to implement a proper control flow and not just go around killing things.

Comment: @KerrekSB You would have to run each thread on a separate computer then.

Comment: Possible deplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626882/c11-get-a-task-finished-by-one-of-two-algorithms/26627805#26627805

Comment: @JosephMansfield: I'd argue that once your program is non-deterministic, you can't really distinguish one thread having been killed from all threads having been killed (in general). So pulling the plug actually does achieve the desired effect and is not distinguishable by use of language rules alone from any other way of achieving this effect :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A program executes a deterministic set of instructions following a set control flow. You cannot arbitrarily interrupt this control flow and still reason about your program behaviour.

Just like you cannot say "run my program, but not for longer than 10 seconds" without the program knowing about this and producing meaningful output, you cannot kill a thread without the thread knowing about it and producing a meaningful program state. In short, "thread cancellation requires cooperation".

Here's a simple way to make your threads cooperate: use a shared flag.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<bool> thread_1_must_end(false);

void foo(int thread_id)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (thread_id == 1 && thread_1_must_end.load()) { break; }
        // do stuff
    }
}

int main()
{
    using std::literals::chrono_literals;

    std::thread t1(foo, 1), t2(foo, 2);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);

    thread_1_must_end.store(true);
    t1.join();  // 1

    // ...

}
```

Note that this procedure is still *cooperative*. The `join()` operation (marked `// 1`) blocks until the thread function loops around and checks the flag. There are no timing guarantees for this. If the thread function ignores the flag, you cannot communicate with it. It is *your* responsibility to give all thread functions enough facilities to learn when it is time to end.

Comment: I have a question to "The join() operation (marked // 1) blocks until the thread function loops around and checks the flag". Wouldn't it block the thread until the flag is false and the other thread exits the infinite loop?

Comment: @Vinzenz: I'm not sure I follow... :-S Both threads run the same thread function concurrently. And I didn't even deal with thread 2 in this example.

Comment: It just sounds like the first thread would only "wait" for the t1 thread until it "loops around and checks the flag". Regardless if the flag is true or false, it would then continue async to the t1 thread. I'm not familiar with std:atomic, so I don't know if that's how the thread behaves then.

Comment: @Vinzenz: Thread 1 exits (by breaking from the loop) when it sees `thread_1_must_end` equal to `true`. That's when `t1.join()` returns.

Comment: Right, that's how I learned it too. I still never got the sense in that as you usually use threads to run something async aka parallel... So I always detach threads