# Access to callable object inside an async task conflicts with use of std::cin

Tags: asynchronous, c++11, task, cin, std-function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <tchar.h>

void StartBackground(std::function<void()> notify)
{
    auto background = std::async([&]
    {
        notify(); // (A)
    });
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    StartBackground([](){});

    char c; std::cin >> c;  // (B)
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

1) Build and run the code above using Visual Studio 2012.

2) Line (A) triggers an Access Violation in `_VARIADIC_EXPAND_P1_0(_CLASS_FUNC_CLASS_0, , , , )`:

> First-chance exception at 0x0F96271E (msvcp110d.dll) in
>   ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
>   0x0F9626D8

Most confusingly, the exception can be avoided by removing line (B).

### Questions

- Why does the callable object `notify` apparently conflict with the use of `std::cin`?
- What's wrong with this code?

The real world scenario for this simplified example is a function that executes some code in parallel and have that code call a user-supplied notify function when done.

### Edit

I found at least one problem im my code: The `background` variable is destroyed as soon as `StartBackground()` exits. Since `std::async` may or may not start a separate thread, and `std::thread` calls `terminate()` if the thread is still joinable, this might be causing the problem.
The following variant works because it gives the task enough time to complete:

```
void StartBackground(std::function<void()> notify)
{
    auto background = std::async([&]
    {
        notify(); // (A)
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

Keeping the `std::future` object alive over a longer period instead of sleeping should also work. But the following code also causes the same access violation:

```
std::future<void> background;

void StartBackground(std::function<void()> notify)
{
    background = std::async([&]
    {
        notify(); // (A)
    });
}
```

whereas using a `std::thread` in the same manner works as expected:

```
std::thread background;

void StartBackground(std::function<void()> notify)
{
    background = std::thread([&]
    {
        notify(); // (A)
    });
}
```

I'm completely puzzled.
I must be missing some very crucial points here regarding `std::async` and `std::thread`.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `async` is a *future*, not a running thread. *You* have to synchronize on the task by saying `background.get()`. Without that, the client procedure may never get executed.

Comment: Thanks for your hint.

It's all about life times.
Here, not only `background` went out of scope but the `notify` function was an rvalue passed into `StartBackground()`, too. 
To rectify my example above, both - the `std::future` and the `std::function` objects - should be lvalues and passed as references.

(The forum Software does not allow me to post a more verbose answer yet).

Comment: @Dr.FrankHeimes: Yeah, lifetime is an issue, too, though the initial code you posted didn't exhibit that. I was in a rush and didn't want to go deeper at the point, but I'll take a look at your edited post. In the meantime, maybe [this post of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12335206/596781) might be of interest.