# is std::packaged_task really expensive?

Tags: performance, gcc, c++11, packaged-task

I am surprised at the results of the following code using gcc 4.7.2 on Opensuse Linux:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main(void)
{
  const long N = 10*1000*1000;
  std::vector<double> array(N);
  for (auto& i : array)
    i = rand()/333.;

  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  for (auto& i : array)
    pow(i,i);
  end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
  std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";

  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  for (auto& i : array)
    std::packaged_task<double(double,double)> myTask(pow);
  elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::system_clock::now()-start;
  std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";

  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  for (auto& i : array)
    std::packaged_task<double()> myTask(std::bind(pow,i,i));
  elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::system_clock::now()-start;
  std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";

  return 0;
}
```

The results look like this (and are fairly consistent amongst runs):

```
elapsed time: 0.694315s
elapsed time: 6.49907s
elapsed time: 8.42619s
```

If I interpret the results correctly, just *creating* a `std::packaged_task` (not even executing it or storing its arguments yet) is already ten times more expensive than `executing` `pow`. Is that a valid conclusion?

Why is this so?

Is this by accident gcc specific?

Comment: Well, naturally, a packaged task contains synchronisation primitives which are expensive -- bus lock and pipeline flush are common consequences of low-level synchronisation primitives, and so single-threaded synchronised will always lose out against single-threaded unsynchronised. You have to actually be able to benefit from concurrent or parallel execution to make a concurrent solution a viable improvement.

Comment: (You can build your own packaged task [with a promise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11004273/596781). The promise alone contains some serious synchronisation mechanics.)

Comment: @KerrekSB, I would be surprised if creating a packaged_task requires that many use of locking primitives. After all, there is no possible contention (yet). And creating that many mutexes just takes 0.09s - so unless you need to create ten mutexes per packaged_task, there's still a lot of room...

Comment: I would look into the implementation of `std::promise` in your library. I haven't looked myself, but I suspect that that's doing something non-trivial even upon initialization.

Comment: Guessing from the implementation in libstdc++ and own tests using g++4.8.1 (at default -O0), there's a lot of time spent in the `packaged_task` case doing roughly this: `make_shared< function<double()> >( bind(..) )` and the successive destruction of it.

Comment: At -O3, all the numbers are roughly the same for me. Actually, I'm surprised anything is executed at all for the loop code.

Comment: [std::packaged_task constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task) invoke that 1) create a shared state (with dynamic memory allocation) and 2) store callable object as std::function-like object into shared state. Furthermore `myTask` will be destroyed immediately by end of its scope, that 3) destroy the shared state (w/ memory dealloc). That operations sequence are more expensive than calling simply `pow` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not timing the execution of a `packaged_task`, only its creation.

```
std::packaged_task<double(double,double)> myTask(pow);
```

This does not execute `myTask`, only creates it. Ideally you shouldn't be measuring this, you should be measuring `myTask(i, i)`, which I did by changing your program to the following (I removed the measuring with `std::bind`).

Results are worse than what you measured:

```
timing raw
elapsed time: 0.578244s

timing ptask
elapsed time: 20.7379s
```

I guess `packaged_task`s are not suitable for repeatable small tasks, the overhead is certainly greater than the task itself. My reading on this is that you should use them for multitasking code, on a task that would take longer than the overhead associated with calling and synchronizing a `packaged_task`.

If you're not multitasking, I think there's no point in wrapping a function call in classes ready for multithreading with synchronization primitives, they're not free, sadly.

For the record, here's what I used:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int main(void)
{
  const long N = 10*1000*1000;
  std::vector<double> array(N);
  for (auto& i : array)
    i = rand()/333.;

  std::cout << "timing raw" << std::endl;
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  for (auto& i : array)
    pow(i,i);
  end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
  std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n\n";

  std::cout << "timing ptask" << std::endl;
  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::packaged_task<double(double,double)> myTask(pow);
  for (auto& i : array)
  {
      myTask(i, i);
      myTask.get_future().wait();
      myTask.reset();
  }
  elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::system_clock::now()-start;
  std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Leonardo, thanks for your elaborate answer. I think you underwrite the conclusion: creating a packaged_task is expensive - using it to offload work to other cores is only feasible for large amounts of work.