# std::promise and std::future in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

> std::promise provides a means of setting a value (of type T), which
>   can later be read through an associated std::future object

1. How exactly these two are associated?
2. Is my concern reasonable that the future would pair with the wrong promise?

update: example from concurrency in action... (the code cannot compile, though)

```
#include <future>
void process_connections(connection_set& connections)
{
    while(!done(connections)){
        for(connection_iterator
        connection=connections.begin(),end=connections.end();
        connection!=end;
        ++connection)
        {
            if(connection->has_incoming_data()){
                data_packet data=connection->incoming();
                std::promise<payload_type>& p=
                connection->get_promise(data.id);
                p.set_value(data.payload);
            }
            if(connection->has_outgoing_data()){
                outgoing_packet data=
                connection->top_of_outgoing_queue();
                connection->send(data.payload);
                data.promise.set_value(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [What is std::promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004273/what-is-stdpromise) for more discussion and a short demo program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Think of `promise` and `future` as creating a single-use channel for data. `promise` creates the channel, and eventually writes the data to it with `promise::set_value`. `future` connects to the channel, and `future::wait` reads and returns the data once it's been written.
2. No real concern, because the only way to "pair" a `future` with a `promise` is with `promise::get_future`.

Comment: i have updated the post. there is no promise::get_future included in the example.

Comment: @Decipher That's because there's no use of `future`. Without a `future`, a `promise` is useless. (As in life!)

Comment: @Decipher Look at the definition of `future`. The publicly-exposed constructors have no way to make a `future` worth waiting on -- the default constructor is basically only there in case you want to assign some other `future` to it later on. If you want a `future`, you need to get it from a producer, like `promise`.

Answer (score 2):

1. They are associated by the `std::promise::get_future` member function. You get the `std::future` associated with an `std::promise` by calling this function.

   A `std::future` represents a value that you do not yet have, but will have eventually. It provides functionality to check whether the value is available yet, or to wait for it to be available.

   A `std::promise` makes a promise that you will eventually set a value. When a value is eventually set, it will be made available through its corresponding `std::future`.
2. No, because you don't pair them after creation. You get your `std::future` from a `std::promise`, so they are inherently linked.

Answer (score 0):

`std::promise<class T> promiseObj;`

1. A promise object creates a container that can store a value of type T

`std::future<class T> futureObj = promiseObj.get_future();`

2. A future object retrieves what is there in container created by promise object as soon as it holds some value. A future object needs to be associated with the container created by promise object, this can be done by the above snippet. **So if you have associated future with intended promise object, it should not be the case that future gets paired with the wrong promise object.**
3. Here is an example program that makes the future-promise usage clear:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <thread>
   #include <future>

   //Some Class will complex functions that you want to do in parallel running thread
   class MyClass
   {
   public:
       static void add(int a, int b, std::promise<int> * promObj)
       {
           //Some complex calculations
           int c = a + b;

           //Set int c in container provided by promise
           promObj->set_value(c);
       }
   };

   int main()
   {
       MyClass myclass;

       //Promise provides a container
       std::promise<int> promiseObj;

       //By future we can access the values in container created by promise
       std::future<int> futureObj = promiseObj.get_future();

       //Init thread with function parameter of called function and pass promise object
       std::thread th(myclass.add, 7, 8, &promiseObj);

       //Detach thread
       th.detach();

       //Get values from future object
       std::cout<<futureObj.get()<<std::endl;

       return 0;
   }
   ```