# Run Member Function in Separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to run a member function in its own thread and have followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998780/stdthread-calling-method-of-class), however in that example, the thread starts and finishes in the same function.  How do you maintain a reference to the thread to join in a separate member function (say the destructor)?  I have tried this:

```
class foo
{
    foo();
    ~foo();
    volatile sig_atomic_t m_run_thread = true;
    std::thread &m_read_thread;
    void read_thread();

}

foo::foo():m_read_thread(std::thread(&foo::read_thread, this))
{
}

foo::~foo()
{
     m_run_thread = false;
     m_read_thread.join();
}

void foo::read_thread()
{
    while(m_run_thread)
    {
    //do something cool
    }
}

int main()
{
   foo bar;
   //do other stuff
}
```

The compiler gives me an error though: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::thread&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::thread’.  This is caused because I'm trying to bind a temporary to a reference. What's this best way to fix this?

Comment: If it did compile, your `m_read_thread` would be a dangling reference after a `foo` is constructed. Why do you have a `thread&` member instead of a `thread`?

Comment: Don't make `m_read_thread` a reference.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but `volatile sig_atomic_t` is crufty old C for coordinating between the main program and a signal handler. Use `std::atomic<bool>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo::foo():m_read_thread(std::thread(&foo::read_thread, this))` is not going to work as `std::thread(&foo::read_thread, this)` is a temporary value and a temporary cannot be bound to a non const lvalue reference.

That said there is no reason to make the thread member a reference.  You can simple have a `std::thread` member like `std::thread m_read_thread;` and then in the constructor you would initialize it like

```
foo::foo() : m_read_thread(std::thread(&foo::read_thread, this))
```