# Start thread with derived class's member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, c++11, derived-class

Similar to this question: [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10673585/4322687) and this one: [std::thread calling method of class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10998780/4322687)

However I have the following:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
class myAbstractClass {
public:
  virtual void myFunction() = 0;//abstract class
}

class myFirstClass : public myAbstractClass {
public:
  void myFunction() { std::cout << "First class here";}
}

class mySecondClass : public myAbstractClass {
public:
  void myFunction() { std::cout << "Second class here";}
}
```

Then I have to call `myFunction()` from a different place in a new thread, but the following does not compile (and I can't think of anything else to try):

```
public void callMemberFunctionInThread(myAbstractClass& myInstance) {
  std::thread myThread (&myAbstractClass::myFunction, myInstance);
  //supposed to call myInstance.myFunction() on myThread
}
```

Comment: "does not compile" isn't very specific.  What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Intellisense doesn't complain, compilation starts and then it gives `C2259 'myAbstractClass': cannot instantiate abstract class` in file `tuple` located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include` (line 199)

Comment: `std::ref(myInstance)`?

Comment: Please fix your program so that it is an [mcve] first. Lots of trivial syntax error here.

Comment: The abstract class member function should be `virtual` if the derived classes are supposed to override it. Don't know if that works with `std::thread` anyway.

Comment: @BoPersson you're right, fixed it

Comment: @peppe Thanks a lot, that fixed it. Do you want me to post it as a new answer so that other people searching for it can find it more quickly?

Comment: @Programming - If you have a complete working example of starting a thread with a virtual function, that would make an interesting answer. Haven't really considered that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `std::ref(myInstance)`. Note that `std::thread` constructor will make a copy of the arguments passed to it (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)), and you can't copy a `myAbstractClass`.

(Then, all of this will still work because `std::thread` functionality is described in terms of `std::invoke`, which unwraps the `std::reference_wrapper` obtained by `std::ref` and calls the pointer to member function onto it. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)).