# Call a method with thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class-method

How to call a class method with thread ?

My class:

```
using namespace std;
class series{
private:
    string filename;
    vector<double> data;
public:
    series(string _filename);
    int loaddata(const int col);
    void readdata() const;

};

series::series(string _filename):filename(_filename) {}

int series::loaddata(const int col)
{
    ifstream input(filename);
    string line;
    if (!input) {
        cout << "File failed to open" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    while(!input.eof())
    {
        while(getline(input, line)){
            vector<string> oneline;
            boost::split(oneline, line, boost::is_any_of("|"));
            data.push_back(boost::lexical_cast<double>(oneline[col]));
        }

    }
    return 1;
}
```

Calling it from main, only posting the relevant part. csv is a vector of filenames, basically vector of strings.

```
vector<series> ts;
int col = 0;
vector<thread> th;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i != csv.size(); ++i) {
    ts.push_back(series(csv[i]));
    th.emplace_back(thread(&series::loaddata, ref(ts[i]), col));
}
```

Gives the error I could not understand.

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<int (series::*)(int)>(std::reference_wrapper<series>, int)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:137:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = int (series::*)(int); _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<series>, int}]’
/home/d066537/ClionProjects/correlation/src/main.cpp:105:66:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<int (series::*)(int)>(std::reference_wrapper<series>, int)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<int (series::*)(int)>(std::reference_wrapper<series>, int)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

Solution please, Using Clion CMake for the program and yes threading works for free functions so I don't think It's matter of any compiler flag.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lpthread -std=c++11")
```

If I remove ref wrapper from object I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' what(): Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
```

Now updated to g++-5, without ref wrapper and again the error:
CMakeFiles/correlation.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function

```
`std::thread::thread<int (series::*)(int), series&, int>(int (series::*&&)(int), series&, int&&)':
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:137: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `ref` wrapper for the object you want to use for the thread function.

Comment: Also note that GCC version 4.8 by now is quite old, and it did not have full C++11 capabilities. Try to update to a later version of GCC and try again.

Comment: If I remove ref wrapper I get this error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted

Comment: Lastly (but unrelated to your problem, which is most likely due to the old and not-fully-c++11 status of your GCC), please take some time to read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Lookup [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998780/stdthread-calling-method-of-class)

Comment: @voltento I saw it before posting it here.

Comment: @Some programmer dude - Update my question with g++-5

Comment: Link with the `pthread` library, or add the `-pthread` flag when building (compiling *and* linking). That's a very different problem than what you originally had, and should have warranted a new question (which would have been closed as a duplicate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s one way to solve the immediate problems I can find in your code. I also added `std::` everywhere because [using namespace std is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

```
std::vector<series> ts;
ts.reserve(csv.size());  // [1]

int col = 0;
std::vector<std::thread> th;
th.reserve(csv.size());  // [1a] optional

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != csv.size(); ++i) {
    ts.push_back(series(csv[i]));
    th.emplace_back(&series::loaddata, &ts[i], col);  // [2]
}

// Lots of other code could be executed here. Joining only has to happen 
// at *some* point after creating the threads.

// [3]
for (auto& thread : th) {
    thread.join();
}
```

#### [2]

Let’s start here because this is the most straight forward problem. The pattern to call a member function with std::thread is:

```
std::thread(ptr-to-member-func, ptr-to-object, member-func-args...);
```

Essentially you have to provide the object that will become `this` when executing `loaddata()`. And it’s called the “this pointer” for a reason. ;)

Also `emplace_back()` is a forwarding function that only takes the constructor arguments of the object you want to put into the vector. Explicitely constructing `std::thread(...)` here defeats the purpose.

#### [3]

This one is also simple. You have to make sure that the threads can do all their work and exit properly. That means calling `join()` at some point, which will block until the thread is done. That’s especially important if you still have threads running when you want to exit your whole program.

Note that calling `join()` inside the for loop like in ΔλЛ’s answer won’t work. If you do it like that you’ll create a single thread, wait for it to finish, and then continue with the next thread. That’s a convoluted way of doing single-threaded execution.

#### [1]

A small reminder on how vector (and basically all other std containers) works. It allocates a block of memory and uses that for the items you `push_back()`. When it runs out of space it allocates a new – larger – block of memory, copies or moves the existing items there and continues to `push_back()`. Reallocation means that all references and pointers to the items as well as all iterators into the vector are invalidated.

Which brings us back to [2]. There you pass a pointer to an item in the vector `ts`. But `ts` *will* have to re-allocate at some point during the loop (at least that’s what you have to assume) – leaving the threads with dangling pointers. That’s classic undefined behaviour.

There are multiple ways to solve that problem. [1] shows a very simple one that works nicely if you know in advance how large the vector will become. `reserve()` allocates enough space for the given number of elements, which prevents reallocation. Your pointers stay valid.

Another solution is to introduce an additional indirection: usually by allocating the items on the heap and storing pointers in the vector. Like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<series>> ts;

for (...) {
    ts.push_back(new series(csv[i]));
    // In C++14 you would use std::make_unique instead of a raw new.

    th.emplace_back(
        &series::loaddata, 
        ts[i].get(),  // notice the difference
        col);
}
```

Now the vector can reallocate as much as it likes. It only needs to copy some pointers to its new memory block. The addresses of the actual `series` objects are not affected anymore.

#### [1a]

Why did I say this is optional? `th` is going to reallocate the same as `ts`. However, you don’t hold on to any refs or pointers to your thread objects. It doesn’t matter if they get invalidated. And `std::thread` is movable, i.e. it will survive reallocation just fine. On the other hand memory allocation is a potentially expensive operation and it’s trivial to avoid in this case.

#### P.S.

Have a look at `std::async` for a more high-level approach to concurrency. Threads are a very low-level construct. If you can, better avoid dealing with them directly.

Comment: I loved your explanation by the way but the join() should be called on th ?

Comment: Oops, yes, of course the “join loop” needs to be over `th`. It’s fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating you pointer as a temporary, stack-allocated variable and  `emplace_back` it into your vector. When you get out of the `for` loop iteration, the desctrutor is executed and `std::terminate` will be called to terminate the running thread.

One way to fix this would be to use `std::vector<std::thread*>` instead:

```
vector<thread*> th;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i != csv.size(); ++i) {
    ts.push_back(series(csv[i]));
    thread t = new thread(&series::loaddata, ref(ts[i]), col)
    th.emplace_back(t);
    th[i]->join();
}
```

Remember to `delete` your threads after you finish loading data.

Comment: Does not work, I tried thread *t = new thread(&series::loaddata, ref(ts[i]), col)

Comment: Forgot to add that you need to use `join()` on each threads (modifed my answer).

Comment: Yes, I could give the answer using `std::async` and `std::future` but I wanted to explain what is wrong with this approach and provide a simple fix OP could easily understand.

Comment: Does not work with ref and if I remove, it works but ts does not load data when loaddata is called from thread :(