# Passing member functions to std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

I have recently been playing around with the new std::thread library in c++11 and I came across a problem. When i try to pass a classes function into a new thread, it gives me an error (I dont have the exact error text right now since im away from home)
I had a class like this

```
class A
{
    void FunctA();
    void FunctB();

    void run()
    {
        std::thread t(FunctA);
        std::thread r(FunctB);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have u tried making FunctA/FunctB static?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
class A
{
    void FunctA();
    void FunctB();

    void run()
    {
        std::thread t(&A::FunctA, this);
        std::thread r(&A::FunctB, this);
    }
};
```

Pointers to member functions are different from pointers to functions, syntax of calling them is different, as well, and requires instance of class. You can just pass pointer to instance as second argument of `std::thread` constructor.

Comment: what if they had args? how would you pass them?

Comment: @kdubs: ...as further arguments to the constructor call. Please do read the docs in the future.

Comment: This code fails! even if you add the `public` keyword..

Comment: I know this is old, but I've been looking for the solution to this. I've seen this answer posted in a few places now, and while this compiles it causes a segfault. Why is this?

Comment: @IronAttorney maybe you need to join or detach the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is that you can't get pointer to member function in a way similar to functions. [Here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) you will find more information about this.

Also, it would be much easier to answer, if you provided compipler error text.