# Calling an objects member function in a thread in main()

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, c++11

I have found a lot about creating a new thread within a class ([Passing member functions to std::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057800/passing-member-functions-to-stdthread))

But is it somehow possible to do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(){
    myInt = 2;
    };
    void myFun(){
        ++myInt;
    }
    int ret_myInt(){
        return myInt;
    }

private:
    int myInt;
};

int main ( void )
{
    myClass myObj_;
    std::thread t1( myObj_.myFun );                 // (1)
    t1.join();
    cout << myObj_.ret_myInt() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The Code is not working, because i cannot call a member function here (1). Is there a simple way to do that?

To be clear: I don't want to create the thread inside the member function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use std::bind:

```
std::thread t1(std::bind(&myClass::myFun, std::ref(myObj_)));
```

Or you can use a lambda, or the variadics interface to the thread constructor.

```
std::thread t3([&myObj_]() { myObj_.myFun(); });    // lambda
std::thread t2(&myClass::myFun, std::ref(myObj_));  // variadics
```

It all comes down to the same.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a function pointer and the object instance as separate arguments to the `thread` constructor:

```
std::thread t1(&myClass::myFun, &myObj);
```

This will cause the `myFun` member function being called, with its first argument being a pointer to the `myObj` instance, just like member functions wants it.

Comment: Aren't you missing a ref?

Comment: @sehe Possibly. So I've made the instance argument a pointer instead so I don't have to worry about it. :)