# How to use std::async on a member function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std

How can I operate std::async call on a member function?

Example:

```
class Person{
public:
    void sum(int i){
        cout << i << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Person person;
    async(&Person::sum,&person,4);
}
```

I want to call to sum async.

```
Person p;
call async to p.sum(xxx)
```

I didnt figure out if i can do it with std::async.
Dont want to use boost.
Looking for a one line async call way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Something  like this:

```
auto f = std::async(&Person::sum, &p, xxx);
```

or

```
auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, &Person::sum, &p, xxx);
```

where `p` is a `Person` instance and `xxx` is an `int`.

This simple demo works with GCC 4.6.3:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  Foo() : data(0) {}
  void sum(int i) { data +=i;}
  int data;
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  auto f = std::async(&Foo::sum, &foo, 42);
  f.get();
  std::cout << foo.data << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It needs to be `std::async(&Person::sum, &p, xxx)`

Comment: & is mandatory for member functions, but optional for free functions.

Comment: I tried but got error  - Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
std::__async_sfinae_helper<std::decay<#0>::type,#0,#1 ...>::type async(#0 &&, #1 && ...)
std::future<std::result_of<#0 (#1 ...)>::type> async(enum std::launch, #0 &&, #1 && ...)
'

Comment: @user1495181 which compiler are you using? It could be that `std::async` isn't properly implemented in your compiler.

Comment: Sorry!!!!!! The error is just eclipse error, the build is passed for your example , but eclipse show errors. However for this example - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async there is no errors in eclipse . errors only show in eclipse for your example

Comment: @user1495181 OK, I see. Eclipse can be a pain with C++11. I still haven't managed to get rid of all the false error warnings.

Comment: @juanchopanza i add the support for c++11 and i already use in c++11 stuff , i dont know why it dosnt love this. can you advice what is why eclipse accept the way in this link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async , but not the way that you suggested?

Comment: @user1495181 I'm not an eclipse expert. The main difference between the codes is that yours uses member functions, and cppreference.com's example uses a non-member, or free, function.

Comment: @user1495181 The bug is in eclipse. Eclipse has poor C+11 support.

Comment: How do you specify the function if it is being overloaded?

Comment: I was able to pass the object by value to std::async and it stilled worked. I thought it was only supposed to work with a reference to the object only.

Comment: std async is horrid, because you can't install a thread pool to be used with it.  if you could it would be fine.

Answer (score 20):

There are several ways, but I find it's most clear to use a lambda, like this:

```
int i=42;
Person p;
auto theasync=std::async([&p,i]{ return p.sum(i);});
```

This creates a `std::future`. For a complete example of this, I have a full example including a async-capable setup of mingw here:

http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/36441490955/eclipse-mingw-builds

You need to make sure that p is thread safe and that the &p reference is valid until the async is joined. (You can also hold p with a shared pointer, or in c++14, a unique_ptr or even move p into the lambda.)

Comment: I tried but got error - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: std::__async_sfinae_helper<std::decay<#0>::type,#0,#1 ...>::type async(#0 &&, #1 && ...) std::future<std::result_of<#0 (#1 ...)>::type> async(enum std::launch, #0 &&, #1 && ...) '

Comment: That error is not a real error, it's just eclipse being confused about C++11. Just go ahead and compile it!

Comment: Yep , i figure out that this is eclipse problem . See  my comment on juanchopanza answer. Some of my code is c++11 and eclipse dosnt has problem with it. I didnt figure out why it has problem with async is certain ways . in this way async work -   en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Comment: The notes section on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) imply that your snippet will actually _not_ run asynchronously. Is it enough to change the call to `std::async(std::launch::async, std::move([&p,i]{ return p.sum(i);}));`?