# async with member function

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

I've a code:

```
class cabc{
public:
    void pr()
    {
        cout<<"abcdef";
    }
};
int main()
{

    cabc cap;
    auto f = async(cap.pr);
    f.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This code is not working. I know the same thing can be done using:

```
auto f = async(&cabc::pr,cap);
```

This is working. But why the first approach is not working?

Comment: Why *would* you expect the first approach to work?

Comment: It's not just `async`, it's just how the language works (or not work).

Comment: cap.pr is function like the regular one. Then why it should not work? @juanchopanza

Comment: No, `cap.pr` is not a function. `cap.pr(arg)` means something like "call `cabc::pr` on `cap` with argument `arg`". `cap.pr` by itself doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's arguable that C++ *should* have a concept of a "bound member function pointer" in the core language, as many people do intuitively expect that the syntax you want to use should work. However, it does not, and adding the feature to the existing type system would not be trivial. On the other hand, it is easy to emulate it on the library level -- it's called `std::mem_fn` and it is internally used by `std::async` to make the `async(&a::b, c)` syntax work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cap.pr` is an incomplete member function call expression. You must follow it with parentheses containing the appropriate function arguments to make a valid C++ expression.

You can't therefore pass `cap.pr` to `std::async` or any other function.

To pass a member function to `std::async` you need to use the syntax you found:

```
auto f=std::async(&capc::pr,cap);
```

Though in this case, you need to be aware that the `cap` object is **copied**. You could also use

```
auto f=std::async(&capc::pr,&cap);
```

to just pass a pointer to `cap`.

If the pointer-to-member-function syntax is unwelcome then you can use a lambda:

```
auto f=std::async([&]{cap.pr();});
```

This isn't quite the same: it doesn't pass the member function pointer and object pointer to `std::async`, it passes a lambda object containing a reference to `cap` that calls its `pr` member function directly. However, the result is essentially the same.

Comment: Nifty - it didn't occur to me to use a lambda there.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the function signature for `async`:

```
template< class Function, class... Args>
std::future<typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type>
    async( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

(from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async))

It should be apparent that, firstly, whatever `Function&&` is, it can't be the case that `cap.pr` and `&cabc::pr` are both of that type.

More precisely, though, `Function&&` is supposed to be an rvalue-reference to a function pointer.  `&cabc::pr` is just the syntax for a pointer-to-member-function, and because it's a member function, a pointer to the object itself needs to be the first argument.  If `cap.pr` were a C-style function pointer, then your first sample might work.

Honestly, I'm not sure why your second sample works since you're not passing in a pointer to your object.

There are a number of other answers to similar questions.  For example: [How to, in C++11, use std::async on a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669094/how-to-in-c11-use-stdasync-on-a-member-function?rq=1)