# Using std::async to call member function returning std::vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, c++11, asynchronous

I know, guys, there is s***t load of posts about `std::async`, but I just cant figure it out myself (for my defense I can say that today was my first day looking at whole multithread & async thing...). 
Here's what I have and what I want it to do - I have a camera and a projector and I want to synchronize them. They are connected so the projector signal triggers acquisition of images. HOWEVER I have to call for acquisiton start before I start displaying images via projector. I am using `OpenCV` as image processing/handling lib.

```
class Camera
{
public::
    //this one captures images till vector reaches given count of images (while loop)
    std::vector<cv::Mat> captureSetOfFrames(uint count = 10)
    {
         std::vector<cv::Mat> vect;
         while(vect.size() < count) { /*try to capture and append to vect */ };
    }
};
class Projector
{
public:
    void start();
    void stop();
}
int main()
{
    Projector *proj = new Projector();
    Camera *cam = new Camera();
    std::vector<cv::Mat> recvimgs;
    recvimgs.reserve(10);
    auto f = std::async(&Camera::captureSetOfFrames, cam, PATTERN_10);
    proj->start();
    while(recvimgs.size() < 10)
        recvimgs = f.get();
    proj->stop();
}
```

I get an error:

```
3   IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands
            operand types are: std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat>> = std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat>> (unsigned short)
```

1. From where this `unsigned short` at the end of error is coming from...?
2. How can I achive this behaviour? (If the code example is not clear enough I want first to prepare for grabbing by calling `Camera::captureSetOfFrames()` then simultaneously call `Projector::start()` but knowing camera is ready for capturing, finally terminate displaying by calling `Projector::stop()` when all images are captured)

Hope you can figure it out!

PS: Base post which suggested me this (not working) solution [How to, in C++11, use std::async on a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669094/how-to-in-c11-use-stdasync-on-a-member-function)

Comment: Are `captureSetOfImages` and `captureSetOfFrames` two functions or a typo? (Also, don't rely too much on IntelliSense – it's just an approximation.)

Comment: Also, this doesn't make much sense. `get()` can be called once on a `future`.

Comment: A future does not deliver partial results. `get` returns the entire result the first time you call it (it waits for the computation to finish if it hasn't) and any further calls are undefined.

Comment: Also, you don't know that `captureSetOfFrames` has been called just because `std::async` returns – all you know is that the function will have been called before `get` returns. If you use the overload you're using it may even be called synchronously when `get` is called, depending on the implementation.

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry of course `captureSetOfImages` and `captureSetOfFrames` is a typo, im gonna fix it in a moment. 
So basicly you say that it can be done like:
`auto f = std::async(&Camera::captureSetOfFrames, cam, 10);
    proj->start();
    recvimgs = f.get();
    proj->stop();` Couse i assume from what you say that `captureSetOfFrames` will be running when i `start()` and it will wait till `f.get()` return a value next?