# std::async with non static member functions

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I am trying to evaluate a part of my code asynchronously

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <future>
#include <map>

namespace IG
{
    typedef std::map<uint, std::string> CadDef;

    class FooFoo
    {
        CadDef foo()
        {
            CadDef cdef{};
            cdef[1] = "aa";
            return cdef;
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<IG::FooFoo>();
    std::future<IG::CadDef> resFut = std::async(ptr->foo);
    auto res = resFut.get();
    return 0;
}
```

But the code doesn't compile -
(On gcc)

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘IG::CadDef IG::FooFoo::foo()’
```

(on msvc -- my main program, from where I abstracted the minimal example)

```
error C3867: 'IG::FooFoo::foo': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
error C2672: 'std::async': no matching overloaded function found
error C2780: 'std::future<_Invoke_traits<void,decay<_Ty>::type,decay<_ArgTypes>::type...>::type> std::async(std::launch,_Fty &&,_ArgTypes &&...)': expects 3 arguments - 1 provided
```

Seems like MSVC is complaining that I have not used `ptr->foo()` but I am not sure.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is accurate. You are trying to call an instance function. But you provide no instance for it to use as `this`. How could it ever work? You probably want a lambda or `std::bind()` that will wrap both the instance and the function to call in a way that can be invoked later. Edit: as the answer linked in my next comment shows, `async` can do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use std::async on a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669094/how-to-use-stdasync-on-a-member-function)

Comment: `std::async(&IG::FooFoo::foo, ptr.get());` or `std::async(&IG::FooFoo::foo, std::ref(*ptr))`.

Comment: @underscore_d and @Evg -- both give me ```error: ‘IG::CadDef IG::FooFoo::foo()’ is private within this context```

Comment: @Roy2511, you should make it `public` for this to work.

Comment: oh damnit, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a lambda like following, <sub>using a policy*</sub>

```
auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async, [&ptr](){
        return ptr->foo(); // Ofcourse make foo public in your snippet
});


auto res = handle.get();
```

---

*<sub>Not [necessarily](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) required</sub>

Comment: Same issue as the other answers in the comments: ```error: ‘IG::CadDef IG::FooFoo::foo()’ is private within this context```

Comment: @Roy2511 you are using a class , so need to make the method public

Comment: Oh damn it, sorry. :(

Answer (score 2):

Async takes a function address as an argument, but it the function is a class-member function you have to bind it to the object which can invoke this function.

All functions (including methods) are moved to the **code segment** of the binary file. 
That's why the **sizeof(T)** equals to sum of sizeof of all class data-members (including a virtual table pointer (**vptr**) if exists).

`class A {void method() };` can be represented as `void method(A* a) {}`

Knowing all this information you should `bind` the method with the object

```
int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<IG::FooFoo>();
    std::future<IG::CadDef> resFut = std::async(&IG::FooFoo::foo, ptr.get());
    auto res = resFut.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The 2nd paragraph seems to try to say there's only one copy of member function per class, hence the need to pass an instance to it when invoking. Is that right? I would only add that `std::bind`-like functors can also take a reference to instance, which doesn't matter much but is sometimes more convenient or just nicer to avoid pointers.

Comment: yes, that's totally right. Sure, std::bind or lambda could be used as well.

Comment: @underscore_d, and it should also be mentioned that such functors copy/move their parameters, so to pass a reference, you need to wrap it into `std::ref`.

Comment: `std::async` probably uses `std::bind` _et al._ under the hood so should accept refs too. Very good point about needing a `reference_wrapper` for functors that take args by value.