# Weird behavihor when calling thread through class member function with another member. CPP

Tags: c++, multithreading

I tried the next code:

```
class JustClass
{
public:
    void JustFunc()
    {
        std::thread t(this->JustThread);
        t.detach();
    }

    void JustThread()
    {

    }

private:

};
```

It should not do any problems. I just call a function of my object to act like a thread.
But I get the next error fot this:

[image: The Eroor I get on the codoe above]

But if Im doing that:

```
class JustClass
{
public:
    void JustFunc()
    {
        std::thread t(this->JustThread, 5);
        t.detach();
    }

    void JustThread(int just_var)
    {

    }

private:

};
```

Then now I get this Eroor:

```
Error   2   error C3867: 'JustClass::JustThread': function call missing argument list; use '&JustClass::JustThread' to create a pointer to member   c:\users\micha\onedrive\מסמכים\visual studio 2013\projects\project2\project2\source.cpp 58  1   Project2
```

Why is that weird behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass member function pointers like this:

```
class JustClass
{
public:
    void JustFunc()
    {
        std::thread t(&JustClass::JustThread, this);
        t.detach();
    }
    void JustThread() {}
private:
};
```

For your second variation:

```
class JustClass
{
public:
    void JustFunc()
    {
        std::thread t(&JustClass::JustThread, this, 5);
        t.detach();
}
void JustThread(int just_var){}
```

---

If the function is overloaded, you will need to select which overload. See [Jonathan Wakely's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14306975/1621391) to a related question. Also read [this FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) about pointers to member functions.

Comment: If you mean why you can just pass non-member functions to `std::thread`, [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150125/why-must-i-use-address-of-operator-to-get-a-pointer-to-a-member-function/42150232#42150232) this question. Also read [this FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)