# c++0x thread initlization

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

While defining a thread constructor with class method in c++0x as shown below, i get function cannot be resolved. What am i doing wrong?

For example, if i have

```
#include <thread>
 using namespace std;
class A
{
 public:
    void doSomething();
    A();
}
```

Then in Class A's constructor, i want to start a thread with doSomething. If i write like below, i get error that doSomething is not resolved. I even this->doSomething.

```
 A::A()
 {
     thread t(doSomething);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
class A
{
 public:
   void doSomething();

   A()
   {
      thread t(&A::doSomething, this);
    }
};
```

OR

```
class A
{
 public:
   static void doSomething();

   A()
   {
      thread t(&A::doSomething);
    }
};
```

Note: you need to join your thread somewhere, for example:

```
class A
{
public:
   void doSomething()
   {
      std::cout << "output from doSomething" << std::endl;
   }

   A(): t(&A::doSomething, this)
   {
   }
   ~A()
   {
     if(t.joinable())
     {
        t.join();
     }
   }

private:
  std::thread t;  
};

int main() 
{
    A a;        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ty, that worked. Will it not work if i dont pass "this" ?

Comment: unless soSomething is static member function

Comment: great!! tys for the response.

Comment: @Jimm, It takes the function, followed by a list of arguments to pass. That function needs an instance.

Comment: In case of static, why would it not be &A::doSomething as opposed to A::doSomething ?

Comment: you can, but not necessary, it has external linkage