# C++ 11 : Start thread with member function and this as parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

Using this code, I got and error :

Error   1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional   1152    1   Pipeline

```
class PipelineJob {
private:
    std::thread *thread;
    void execute(PipelineJob* object);
public:

    void execute(PipelineJob* object)
    {
    }

    PipelineJob()
    {
        this->thread = new std::thread(&PipelineJob::execute, this);
    }
};
```

I tried many variation, any one now how to solve this?

Comment: The design with pointers and `new` is silly and terrible. You should use a constructor initializer list.

Comment: Also, your code makes no sense. Is `PipelineJob` a class or a template?

Comment: hmm, I tried with initialization list, but I was still getting an error of build because I was trying to access the default constructor which doesn't exist.

Comment: I removed all code not useful for the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Comment: Why is `execute` declared twice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Removing the templates and the pointers for simplicity, this is more or less what you would want:

```
class PipelineJob 
{
private:
    std::thread thread_;
    void execute(PipelineJob* object) { ..... }
public:
    PipelineJob()
    {
      thread_ = std::thread(&PipelineJob::execute, this, this);
    }
    ~PipelineJob() { thread_.join(); }
};
```

Note that `this` is passed two times to the `std::thread` constructor: once for the member function's implicit first parameter, the second for the visible parameter `PipelineJob* object` of the member function.

If your `execute` member function does not need an external `PipelineJob` pointer, then you would need something like

```
class PipelineJob 
{
private:
    std::thread thread_;
    void execute() { ..... }
public:
    PipelineJob()
    {
      thread_ = std::thread(&PipelineJob::execute, this);
    }
    ~PipelineJob() { thread_.join(); }
};
```

Comment: And what's the point of passing `this` twice? I think the OP just misunderstood what member functions are...

Comment: Nope, I know what's a member function ;). We don't need "this" twice. when using a static function you don't need to give this reference. But with a none-static it is needed. That way in the function you can use directly this keyword. So you should remove from execute function the parameter since we can access this.

Comment: @pikaille correct. But if you could call `execute` with different `PipelineJob` instances. In this example I use `this` twice, but it doesn't have to be like that. You could have pointers to two different `PipelineJob` instances.

Comment: @Yakk some concern about the object not being fully constructed when the thread starts. I don't know what `execute` does with `this`. Probably just being over cautious.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes there could be a use case, in mine I just needed the this reference, so the second this becomes useless.