# C++11: Start thread in object with member function and this

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have the follwing three files:

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass {
private:
    std::thread* thread = NULL;
    void run();
public:
    ~MyClass();
    void start();
}
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
MyClass:~MyClass() {
    if (thread != NULL)
        thread -> join();
}

void MyClass::run() {
    //do stuff
}

void MyClass::start() {
    thread = &std::thread (&MyClass::run, this);
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
int main() {
    MyClass obj{};
    obj.start();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I always get `R6010 - abort() has been called` and I don't know why `abort()` is called. When I create the thread in the main function it works, but for design reasons I want to start it in `MyClass`. This there a way to start the thread in `MyClass`?

P.S.:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718663/c-11-start-thread-with-member-function-and-this-as-parameter) question is quite similar, but the answers didn't solve my problem.

Comment: _' This question is quite similar, but the answers didn't solve my problem.'_ Why? I'd also urgently recommend to use a plain `std::thread` member, instead of a `std::thread*` pointer.

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to `std::thread` and taking the address of a temporary? (which should have caused a compilation error)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because the handle to `std::thread` is destroyed (goes out of scope) before it's either `join`ed or `detach`ed.

I suggest:

```
class MyClass {
private:
    std::thread thread;
    void run();
public:
    ~MyClass();
    void start();
}
```

and:

```
MyClass:~MyClass() {
    if (thread.joinable())
        thread.join();
}

void MyClass::run() {
    //do stuff
}

void MyClass::start() {
    thread = std::thread (&MyClass::run, this); //Move assignment
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either keep a `std::thread` member or use `new` to create the thread pointer. As it is, your `std::thread` object is going out of scope at the end of `start()` and that results in terminate being called on the thread.