# C++ Calling member function in boost thread

Tags: c++, boost-thread

So I want to start member function `Open()`  in a boost thread:

**.hpp**

```
Class MyClass{
  public:
    int Open();
  private:
    void handle_thread();
};
```

**.cpp**

```
int MyClass::Open(){
    boost::thread t(handle_thread);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}

void MyClass::handle_thread(){
  //do stuff
}

test.cpp
int main(){
     MyClass* testObject = new MyClass()
     testObject.Open();
}
```

This results in  a compiler error.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'boost::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

I see that Open() doesn't know on which object to call handle_thread. But I cannot figure out what the correct syntax is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Answer (score 1):

`handle_thread` is a member function and must be called as such:

```
int MyClass::Open(){
    boost::thread t(&MyClass::handle_thread, this);
    ...
}
```

Note that if you `join`the thread immediately afterwards, you function will be blocking. The behavior will be identical to that of a single-threaded application, besides the fact that `handle_thread` actually runs on a different thread. There will be no interleaving of threads (i.e. no parallelism) though.

Comment: How can I manage that my function `Open` will keep running after I start the thread?

Comment: @tzippy `std::thread`is movable. You can return the thread object from `Open`and do the join outside. Depending on the nature of the thread, it might make sense to instead detach the thread and return a [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) (similar to what [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) does).