# How to call callback in member function thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, serial-port

I'am writing small class for RS232 port. It can sync write and async read. So, for async read I'm using second thread, that waiting input data. When data received, I want to call user callback (that I get as constructor argument) with input data. It's look like:

```
typedef int (*ReceivedCallback)(string data);

class RS232
{
    RS232(string portName, ReceivedCallback dataReceived);
    ~RS232();

private:
    ReceivedCallback dataReceivedCallback;

private:
    static unsigned ReaderThread(void* data);

public:
    SendData(string data);
}
```

My problem is: ReaderThread MUST be static to pass pointer to it to _beginthreadex() function. And in ReaderThread I want to call "dataReceivedCallback", obtained from the user in constructor. But I can't, cause I can't call non-static functions in static ReaderThread. Also, I can't make "dataReceivedCallback" static, cause I may have many instances of my class (for COM1, COM2, COM3) and every instance should have it's own callback, obtained by user.

Where is my architecture mistake? How would you implement it?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Using Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: If C++11 is possible, then an std::thread can be started with member function.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass an extra argument to the thread function (which you already have a `void *data` available for).

Now, add this as a private element in your `class RS232`:

```
class RS232
{

     RS232(string portName, ReceivedCallback dataReceived);
    ~RS232();

private:
    ReceivedCallback dataReceivedCallback;

private:
    static unsigned ReaderThread(void* data);

public:
    SendData(string data);
}
```

and in the constructor:

```
RS232::RS232(string portName, ReceivedCallback dataReceived)
{
   ... various stuff to initialize the serial port ... 
   _beginthreadex(securityarg, stacksize, ReaderThread, this, ...)
}
```

And in the ReaderThread function:

```
unsigned RS232::ReaderThread(void *data)
{
   RS232 *self = static_cast<RS232*>(data);

   .... stuff to read from serial port ... 

   ... Now call the callback:
   self->dataReceivedCallback(str); 
   .... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a pointer to the instance of `RS232` to `ReaderThread`, which will, in turn, either pass that pointer to a `static` callback, or directly call non-`static` methods on the `RS232` object.

I would also use `[CreateThread][1]` rather than `beginthreadex`.  My code samples will use `CreateThread`, but you can adapt the technique to `beginthreadex` if you so desire.

Simply, when kicking off the `ReaderThread`, pass it a pointer to the instance:

```
RS232* myObj = new RS232;
CreateThread (..., myObj);
```

...use `reinterpret_cast` to cast it back:

```
unsigned RS232::ReaderThread (void* data)
{
  RS232* that = reinterpret_cast <RS232*> (data);
}
```

Change your callback function so that it can pass the instance as well:

```
typedef int (*ReceivedCallback)(string data, RS232* that);
```

And now in the callback you can call member functions:

```
that->DoSomethingCool (data);
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the non-static object data in the static thread function you could use this extremely hacky and untested solution. But be warned --- it is for educational purposes only because it is extremely hacky. You should learn about locks and mutexes and probably boost threads. Note, this is a pthread style solution. I've no experience with the function _beginthreadex() but you can see that createThread does the job of creating your thread. Adapt as needed.

```
typedef int (*ReceivedCallback)(string data);

class RS232
{
public:
    RS232(string portName, ReceivedCallback dataReceived);
    ~RS232();
    SendData(string data);
    createThread();

private:
    ReceivedCallback dataReceivedCallback;
    static unsigned ReaderThread(void* data);
    thread m_someThread;

    struct accessHelper
    {
        RS232* This;
        void *actual_arg;
        accessHelper(RS232 *t, void *p)  
            : This(t), 
              actual_arg(p) 
              {}
    };

};

RS232::createThreaad()
{
     int someData;
     accessHelper ah(this, someData);
     m_someThread.create(RS232::ReaderThread, &ah);
}

RS232::ReaderThread(void *data) 
{
    accessHelper *ah = static_cast<accessHelper*>(data);
    RS232 *This = ah->This;
    This->dataReceivedCallback......
}
```