# Cannot pass class member-function to another function(std::thread::thread)

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member, stdthread

Take a look at these 2 codes.

The code below works fine.

```
void someFunction () {

    // Some unimportant stuff
}

MainM::MainM(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

    std::thread oUpdate (someFunction);

}
```

This code throws an error:

```
void MainM::someFunction () {      //as a class member


}


MainM::MainM(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

    std::thread oUpdate (someFunction);

}
```

Error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
     std::thread oUpdate (someFunction);
                                     ^
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function) - did you even try searching for an existing answer?

Comment: @JonathanWakely It is, sorry. It is not ONLY std::thread related, so...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't create a *pointer-to-member-function* by applying `&` to *just the name*. You need the fully qualified member: `&MainM::someFunction`.

And also bind it to an instance, by passing `this`, e.g.

```
#include <thread>

struct MainM
{
    void someFunction() {
    }

    void main() 
    {
        std::thread th(&MainM::someFunction, this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    MainM m;
    m.main();
}
```