# Multithreading with overloaded member functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, syntax-error

Compiling with

```sh
$ g++ -std=c++0x -I "inc" src/*.cpp
```

and receiving

```
src/ProcessGroup.cpp:25:10: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::thread'
  thread t(&Process::Run, p, exit_code);
         ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:349:9: note: candidate template
      ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Fp'
thread::thread(_Fp&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
        ^
```

`g++` is complaining that it cannot find a matching constructor for the arguments I give it:

```
void
ProcessGroup::Add(Process *p)
{
  Process::status_t *exit_code = new Process::status_t;
  thread t(&Process::Run, p, exit_code);
  instance_t *instance = new instance_t(&p, &t);
  threads.insert(pair<instance_t*, Process::status_t*> (instance, exit_code));
}

// FIXME: Should *not* be using system(); this was just a standup to
// test multithreading
Process::status_t
Process::Run() const
{
  return system(command.c_str());
}

void
Process::Run(Process::status_t &exit_code)
{
  exit_code = Run();
}
```

As far as I can tell, I am asking the compiler for the constructor which matches

```
thread( <some function>, <some object>, <some argument>... )
```

which *should* work according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10673671/1443496) to [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10673585/1443496).  It doesn't, so obviously something must be wrong, but what is it?

The entire code is available on [GitHub](http://github.com/vermiculus/swift).  I apologize to people looking at this post in the future—the history of that repository will likely be rewritten.

Comment: `Process::Run` is overloaded, so you have to select an overload.

Comment: `new instance_t(&p, &t);` <--`t` is a local variable and you're taking its address. This is probably not going to go well later...

Comment: @dyp I thought it might have had something to do with that, which is why I included the overloaded definitions.  How do I select one?

Comment: @DarkFalcon Yeah, there's a whole lot wrong with the code!  This is a prototype project and this is the first time i've compiled. Most of this was written between 1–2am. :)

Comment: Use either a `static_cast` (like `static_cast<void (Process::*)(void)>(&Process::Run)` or pass a function object with overloaded `operator()` (or wrap the function). Using a lambda: `[](Process* ptr, Process::status_t& st) { ptr->Run(st); }`

Comment: Use a lambda: `std::thread t{[=]{ p->Run(*exit_code); });` or better, `std::thread t{[=]{ *exit_code = p->Run(); });` and you won't need to overload `Run`. Also, the next problem you will have is that `std::terminate` will be called from `t`'s destructor at the end of `Process::Add`: a joinable thread must be joined or detached before the thread object is destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
std::thread t(static_cast<void(Process::*)(Process::status_t&)>(&Process::Run),
              p, std::ref(*exit_code));
```

Since your member function is overloaded, you need to specify the desired overload explicitly. Note also the reference: objects of `std::thread` *own* all their bound state, so reference semantics to outside state have to be made explicit. *And* you need to dereference the pointer `exit_code`, of course.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the delay in accepting.  The error I ran up  against (after this one) ended up having nothing to do with this particular issue. :)