# declare a thread of member function as a member of the class in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, member-functions

How to declare a thread inside a class which run a member function?
I tried several approaches according to online search :
this

```
std::thread t(&(this->deQRequest));
```

this

```
std::thread t([this]{ deQRequest(); });
```

this

```
std::thread t(&this::deQRequest, this);
```

or

```
std::thread t(&this::deQRequest, *this);
```

None of them works.

Then I tried the following code, it works:

```
    std::thread spawn() {
        return std::move(
            std::thread([this] { this->deQRequest(); })
            );
    }
```

but my question is, why this

```
   std::thread t([this]{ deQRequest(); });
```

doesn't work?  it always reminds an error: "Explicit type is missing, 'int' assumed" and "expected a declaration" .

My deQRequest function is a member function in the same class, my class looks like this:

```
  class sender{
      public:
          void deQRequest(){
             //some execution code
          };
      private:
        // here I try to declare a thread like this:std::thread t([this]{ deQRequest(); });
   }
```

Comment: How did you declare `deQRequest`? Also have a look at [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Comment: I already looked at this, the worked code come from there, but my question is different, I don't know why I can't declare the thread like normally I would do outside the class

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I tried "std::thread t((std::bind(&this::deQRequest, this)));" it doesn't work. The error is "expected a type specifier". I think in the first parameter I should refer to the class name instead of "this", but how to refer the class name inside the same class?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I added the deQRequest code in the question post. :)

Comment: @strisunshine And it's a plain member function of which class please? What's `this` referring to in your context dude?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  like I said they are members of the same class, "this" refer to that class, added my class appearance in the post '

Comment: @strisunshine In general we have the rule here, that you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for questions about erroneous/not working code.

Comment: If `std::thread t((std::bind(&this::deQRequest, this)));` doesn't compile, you should try to find out which expression there doesn't compile. You will find that it's not a problem related to threads or `std::bind()`. And, `this` does *not* refer to a class but to an object, in C++ those are distinct things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but my question is, why this
>
> ```
> std::thread t([this]{ deQRequest(); });
> ```
>
> doesn't work? it always reminds an error: 
>      "Explicit type is missing, 'int' assumed" and "expected a declaration".

It's not valid lambda function syntax. `this` is an implicit parameter of `deQRequest`, and can't be passed this way.

As from [`std::thread`'s constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) it takes a function parameter, and the arguments that should be passed there:

```
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

Your class

```
 class sender{
 public:
    void deQRequest(){
        //some execution code
    };
 private:
    void foo() { // I just assume you're using some private function
        // here I try to declare a thread like 
        // this:std::thread t([this]{ deQRequest(); });
    }

    std::thread theThread; // I also assume you want to have a `std::thread`
                           // class member.
 }; // <<< Note the semicolon BTW
```

declares a member function, and you need to [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) that member function to a (your current) class instance:

```
    void foo() {
       theThread = std::thread(std::bind(&sender::deQRequest,this));
    }
```