# Using threads with Classes in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, object

Say I have an object called myObject of class myClass. It has a function

```
void myFunction()
```

What is the syntax to call this function with a thread?

I tried

```
std::thread myThread(myObject.myFunction)
```

but I'm given a syntax error and can't seems to find the correct syntax.

The error message is:

function "std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Always specifiy the exact text of any error messages.

Comment: "I'm given a syntax error" ..... You should show the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
std::thread myThread(std::bind(&myClass::myFunction, myObject));
```

Being, `myClass` the class name of `myObject`. This is the syntax for a pointer-to-member-function.

Also, you can add any other argument your `myFunction` requires just after `myObject`.

Answer (score 0):

according to GCC , here is the error : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fcba365c9b25d1e

which makes sense, because member function is bound to `this` pointer , member variabes and many more. I'd go with lambda expression :

```
std::thread t ([&]{
   myObject.myFunction();
})
```

working example : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0be834a7249bfac9

btw, this practice of wrapping everything with anonymous function is very common in JavaScript, and should be used also here

Answer (score 0):

Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function).

```
std::thread myThread(&myClass.myFunction, myObject)
```