# c++ multi-threading I got an error in the functional header that says

Tags: multithreading, c++11

when I try to create new thread inside my class i get an error in the functional header that says :
Error   1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 4 arguments    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional   1149    1   Puzzel-8

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
this is my calling to create the new thread :

```
thread s(&puzzle::new_thread, state, dir_downn, ini_0_position_i,     ini_0_position_j);
s.detach();
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
and this is the new_thread function :

```
enter code here

void puzzle::new_thread(int * state1[], int move_direction, int     ini_0_position_i, int ini_0_position_j)
{
    int **state2;
    state2 = new int*[puzzle_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < puzzle_size; i++)
    {
        state2[i] = new int[];
    }
    copy_array(state1, state2);
    path_increment(initial_0_position_j, initial_0_position_i, state2,     move_direction);
    goal(state2);``
    the_main(state2, ini_0_position_i, ini_0_position_j);

}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////
note : when I try to create a thread in the main() it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, it appears, is related to the fact, that you're trying to invoke class method to serve as thread entry point. If you do this, first argument shall be `this` pointer, pointing to the object of the class

UPDATE

try something like

```
thread s(&puzzle::new_thread, &puzzle_obj, state, dir_downn, ini_0_position_i,     ini_0_position_j);
```

UPDATE

Good discussion here [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)