# Initialize C++ Thread and Run Later

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm assuming there's an easy answer to this question. I want to first define a thread as a member variable of a class, and then later start this thread in a different function.

For example:

The header file:

```
#include<thread>
class Foo{
public:
   void threaded_method();
   void start_thread();
private:
   std::thread m_thread;      
};
```

Cpp file:

```
void Foo::start_thread(){
    m_thread = std::thread(threaded_method);
}
```

Although the above does not work, thoughts?

Comment: As far as I can see from the docs, that _should_ work. What exactly do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - threads are supposed to be move-assignable.

Comment: `threaded_method` is a member function, that can't be passed to the thread this way. Assigning `m_thread` from another instance is perfectly fine, and should do what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To pass a member function to a thread, you must also pass an instance on which to execute that function.

```
void Foo::start_thread(){
    m_thread = std::thread(&Foo::threaded_method, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a good example in these pages:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable
- [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

I forgot to pass in a valid reference to the member function.

```
void Foo::start_thread(){
    m_thread = std::thread(&Foo::threaded_method, this);
}
```

Should work. Love finding the answer right after I post a question...

Answer (score 0):

You might also simply change your architecture. For example, have a list and which would contain the functions you want to perform. Then multithread your way through all the functions you want to run.