# invalid use of void expression with thread and an object

Tags: c++, multithreading, object

I want to create a thread of the function ahrs thats in my AHRS class. This function is in an infinite loop and calcs something the whole time and puts those calculations in variables. I want to pass those variables to my PID

```
int main() {

    AHRS* a = new AHRS();
    std::thread ahrs(a->ahrs());

    PID* p = new PID();
    float pitch;
    while(1) {
        pitch = a->getPitch();
        std::cout << "pitch: " << pitch << " pid: " << p->getError(0, pitch, 1) << std::endl;
        usleep(100000);
    }   
}
```

but i get the error

```
main_ahrs.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main_ahrs.cpp:26:28: error: invalid use of void expression
```

my ahrs.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "AHRS.h"

AHRS::AHRS() {
    //something
}

AHRS::~AHRS() {}

void AHRS::ahrs() {
    //something
    while(1) {
        //something
    }
}

float AHRS::getPitch() {
    //return something
}

float AHRS::getRoll() {
    //return something
}

float AHRS::getYaw() {
    //return something
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Comment: For thread with member function as an entry point, first parameter supposed to be `this`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: Only if `*this` is the instance you wish to invoke the member function on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
#include <functional>
```

and then:

```
std::thread ahrs(std::bind(&AHRS::ahrs, a));
```

The way you are doing, you are calling the `a->ahrs()` method, that returns `void`. You must pass in to `std::thread` something that can be called: a function pointer, or something like that, not `void`.

In this case of my suggestion, you will pass to `std::thread` the return from `std::bind`, that is a callable object built with a pointer to the method and a pointer to the `AHRS` object.

Comment: binding is actually not required, thread with help of variadic templates will do the job by itself

Answer (score 4):

```
a->ahrs()
```

That is not how you name a function. That is how you call an expression and use its result for something. The result of the function is of `void` type (that is, *there isn't one*) so using this function call as an expression (and certainly for a function reference/object/handle/wrapper/pointer!) is just not going to work.

The function is called `AHRS::ahrs`.

A further complication is that it is a member function, so you have to bind the implicit `this` parameter, like so:

```
std::thread ahrs(std::bind(&AHRS::ahrs, a));
```

The binding creates a sort of pseudo-function reference that already has the first argument sorted out for you, so that you (or, in this case, the `thread` code, which has no ability or desire to guess what the object instance should be) does not need to.

Conveniently, `thread` can do the binding for you, though, so:

```
std::thread ahrs(&AHRS::ahrs, a);
```

should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda is your friend.

```
int main() {
  AHRS* a = new AHRS();
  std::thread ahrs(a->ahrs());
```

what the above does is it **calls** `a->ahrs()` (in `main`), takes its return value and passes it to the `thread` constructor.  This isn't what you want.

Instead:

```
  AHRS* a = new AHRS();
  std::thread ahrs([a]{a->ahrs();});
```

will create a closure (or lambda) that consists of "do a call of `a->ahrs()`".

It then passes that closure to `std::thread`, which runs it on a different thread.

The `[a]` says "this is a closure, and it captures a (copy of) `a`".  Then the body `{a->ahrs();}` says what the closure does.

In general, passing lambdas to `std::thread` is easier to reason about than passing the alternatives.  There is a modest problem in that move-parameters require C++14 to work.

Using `std::bind` or the variardic constructor of `std::thread` are alternatives.  I prefer passing code to passing data in this case, and passing a lambda closure is basically passing code.

Comment: I never understood that before!