# compiler error when calling a std::thread function with parameters C++

Tags: c++, stdthread

I am trying to invoke a function from a new thread. The function takes a bunch of parameters.

```
std::thread signingThread(curlWrapper->SendDataToServer,username, password, serverURL, data);
```

Here is the function protoype

```
int LibCurlWrapper::SendDataToServer(const std::string& username, const std::string& password, const std::string& serverURL, const std::vector<unsigned char> &vData)
```

**Compiler Error**

> error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(, std::string&, std::string&, std::string&, std::vector&)'
>                    std::thread signingThread(curlWrapper->SendDataToServer,username, password, serverURL, data);

Comment: `curlWrapper->SendDataToServer` is nonsense, that's not valid C++. There are **hundreds** of questions on StackOverflow about launching a `std::thread` to run a member function.

Comment: LibCurlWrapper *curlWrapper =  new LibCurlWrapper;
Why is that nonsense?

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely
Also, I have searched a lot before posting this...but nothing that I saw or read has worked. If you have a link please do share. Thnx

Comment: Because you can't refer to a member function like that. You can use `curlWrapper->SendDataToServer` in a function call if you follow it with an argument list, but you didn't do that. You need to construct the thread with a pointer-to-member-function that refers to the member function and with a pointer/reference to the object to call the function on. Here's one example of an existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function/10673671#10673671

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a function to `std::thread`, while `curlWrapper->SendDataToServer` doesn't and couldn't. (Although `curlWrapper->SendDataToServer()` means call `SendDataToServer()` on `curlWrapper`.)

Change it to:

```
std::thread signingThread(&LibCurlWrapper::SendDataToServer, curlWrapper, username, password, serverURL, data);
```

Comment: When I try what you have suggested I get the following compiler error.
error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<int (LibCurlWrapper::*)(const std::basic_string<char>&, const std::basic_string<char>&, const std::basic_string<char>&,  const std::vector<unsigned char>&)>(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>,  std::vector<unsigned char>)>'
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^

Comment: @nateN What compiler are you using? I tried clang, it compiles fine. (Although got a link error.) http://rextester.com/YYSX61209

Comment: ahh...missed one detail...forgot to add the second parameter curlWrapper. Now it works! Thank you

Comment: @nateN Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)