# Why can't I use auto with std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, auto

I'm facing a problem with `std::thread` because it doesn't accept functions taking auto-specified arguments. Here is some sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void seev(const auto &v) // works fine with const vector<int> &v
{
    for (auto x : v)
        cout << x << ' ';
    cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1 { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    thread t(seev, v1);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

But the compiler says:

```
[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::vector<int>&)'
```

Why is this happening? Is it a problem with the language or GCC (4.9.2)?

Comment: @AnkitAcharya No, it's not. It's a gcc extension and proposed for C++17.

Comment: `void seev (const auto &v)` is terrible code IMHO. Explicit is better than implicit, you should write the template.

Comment: @Synxis, i guess it gives an easier generic access to functions so i differ by what you are thinking

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Think about `auto` as a template argument then your function looks like:

```
template <class T>
void seev (const T &v) ...
```

C++ cannot incarnate template without explicit spec of types. That is why you get an error. To fix issue (with template argument declaration) you can use:

```
thread t (seev<decltype(v1)>, std::ref(v1));
```

Comment: this fails too bro, try something else

Comment: @AnkitAcharya just checked on VS-2013 compiled well. Please pay attention to my note about "(with template argument declaration)" so you have use `template <class T>
void seev (const T &v)`

Comment: @AnkitAcharya Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function/10673671#10673671), third paragraph!!!

Comment: You can also fix this by avoid pass vector by value just use `std::ref` as follow: `thread t (seev<decltype(v1)>, std::ref(v1));`  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff9ce57149fbaa47

Comment: Hey meta police, how about you delete the useless comments next time instead of my useful ones that answer his questions!

Answer (score 13):

```
void seev (const auto &v)
```

is not valid C++ (yet, it is proposed for C++17). gcc would have told you had you compiled with `-pedantic`.