# How to make a extern thread of a class function

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

There is a topic about 
[Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

And this is one given example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class bar {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "hello from member function" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   std::thread t(&bar::foo, bar());
   t.join();
}
```

But now the problem is I need to use thread variable in different functions, so I will need to split codes into two parts which are `std::thread t(&bar::foo, bar());` and `t.join();`

I use this below:

```
class A {
public:
    std::thread t;
    void foo();
    void use0();
    void use1();
}

A::foo()
{
}

A::use0()
{
    std::thread t(&A::foo);
}

A::use1()
{
    t.join();
}
```

And I get a error saying `std::invoke : No match was found for the overloaded function`.

What should I do? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To execute a non-static member function in another thread, you need to pass the instance of your class, too:

   ```
   std::thread t(&A::foo, this);
   ```
2. You're creating a local `std::thread` in `use0` (and you're not calling `std::thread::join` before its destruction). Assign to the member `t` instead:

   ```
   t = std::thread(&A::foo, this);
   ```
3. You're missing a semicolon after class definition and the return types (`void`s) in your member function definitions.

Comment: Oh, yes, I missed "void". I know I need to, but here I forgot to write it. Thank you again.