# Threading in object-oriented, event-driven application

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to spawn a thread when a certain trigger event is received inside of a class Foo. The trigger event is received by a Winsock server class that has a reference to the variable `triggerEvent`.

```
bool Foo::HandleEvents()
{
    while (1)
    {
        // Other things are done at the top of this loop

        switch (triggerEvent)
        {
            case 'h':
            {
                // I instantiate an object here to do 
                // what I need to do in the thread.
                // I use a pointer that is a private
                // member of Foo.
                thingMaker = new ThingMaker(params);

                // Spawn a new thread here calling a
                // function of ThingMaker and using thingMaker
                break;
            }
            case ...: return true;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Since the thread is local to its case in the `switch`, I lose access to it on `break`. I can't call `join()` because I'm dealing with real-time processing and cannot wait for the thread to finish unless I know it's already done.

I recently asked a question about threading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110434/starting-a-thread-from-a-member-function-while-inside-another-classs-member-fun) regarding the same application and was told `detach()` is bad practice; I also think my question was too vague as the solution offered ended up not fitting my needs and my application has since changed in architecture.

I have also tried to encapsulate the thread in short-life manager class that creates instances of ThingMaker but to no avail.

How do I go about this? I suspect my main issue is scope, but my options are limited. `Foo::HandleEvents()` cannot be delayed at all or else I lose critical data.

Comment: Have you considered a system where you *do* control the thread lifetimes, such as a thread-pool where the posted code posts your `params` to a queue monitored by the pool for work to be dispatched?

Comment: How about dealing with `futures` ? Do you have C++11 ?

Comment: Why not make the `thread` a member of the `Foo` class then you always have access to it? A question I have is what do you want to happen if the thread is still executing when `HandleEvent` function is triggered? You may need data member to track all the outstanding threads ...

Comment: @WhozCraig I did try a vector of threads that was declared before the `while(1)` loop, and each time `triggerEvent` was 'h', I added a thread to the vector. When the termination event trigger was received, I iterated through the vector and called `join()` on each thread. The issue with a proper thread pool is that the thread needs to end - the thread function returns.

Comment: @JamesAdkison `HandleEvents` is the driving function of the application. It's running until the application is terminated.

Comment: @cjclough That's not a thread pool.  In its simplest form, a set of threads are started, all of them waiting on the queue for work. A thread pool fundamentally is setup as a (usually, but not always fixed) collection of threads that (a) monitor a shared workload resource such as a queue, and (b) upon receiving data from that queue, invoke a work function to process the item just-dequeued. Once finished, the thread returns back to the queue for more work (where it may-well wait if there is none to dispatch). it is much more involved than simply declaring a vector of threads.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah, I understand now, thank you. I think this might work. My only concern is that my "item" is a series of files saved to disk, the range of which is determined and changeable by the end user.

Comment: @cjclough Instead of using a break statement, try using a goto statement. That may allow you to continue access to the thread.

Comment: @code0 `goto` is terrible practice, and `switch` cases have their own scope.

Comment: @cjclough If used wisely and infrequently (to know exactly where it is in the program in case problems arise), it is a simple and easy way to jump around a program efficiently. I like this explanation: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_alternatives_for_goto_statements_in_C As for the switch statement scope problem, why not use if-else statements? Just using this might solve your problem because its avoiding the local scope of the switch statement.

Comment: @code0 Point taken regarding `goto`, but if-else statements have their own scope as well. You cannot access a thread declared in `if (triggerEvent == 'h')` outside of that block.

Comment: @cjclough That's a piece of information that I haven't learned at all in the time I've been programming. Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) (or one of the other similar containers):

```
class Foo
{
    bool HandleEvents();
    std::map<ThingMaker*, std::thread> m_map;
};

bool Foo::HandleEvents()
{
    while (1)
    {
        switch (triggerEvent)
        {
            case 'h':
            {
                thingMaker = new ThingMaker(params);
                m_map[thingMaker] = std::thread(function_ptr, thingMaker);
            } break;
            case 't': // termination event trigger
            {
                m_map[thingMaker].second.join();
                m_map.erase(thingMaker);
                delete thingMaker;
            } break;
            case ...: return true;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Since this obviously isn't your full code you'd have to adjust the above code to fit your needs, but you could swap the map's key/value in the template, or use the thread ID instead if that would make more sense (e.g. `std::map<std::thread::id, ThingMaker*>`, etc.), but something like a `map` avoids iterating over an array and `join`ing on each thread or having to implement a full thread pool implementation if you don't necessarily need one.

**Side note**: the use of [`detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) is not bad, in fact it's quite useful; detaching a thread signals to the kernel that the thread can be "cleaned up" as soon as it's done executing (which releases certain resources and handles). Calling `detach` on a thread is useful when you know you will no longer need access to the underlying thread handle (like in an extremely short lived thread). It's neither bad nor good, simply a tool to utilize (like the infamous `goto` statement).

Hope that can help.

Comment: Awesome answer. Works great. Thanks for the clarification on `detach` also.