# no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

I have been working on a rather simple facility: a concurrent **`for`** loop construct that takes a list of input elements, an output vector, and a function that computes output elements out of input elements.

I have this snippet that does not compile:

```
            template<class In, class Out>
            void thread_do(net::coderodde::concurrent::queue<In>& input_queue,
                           Out (*process)(In in),
                           std::vector<Out>& output_vector)
            {
                // Pop the queue, process, and save result.
                ...
            }


                for (unsigned i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i) 
                {
                    thread_vector.push_back(std::thread(thread_do, 
                                                        input_queue,
                                                        process,
                                                        output_vector));
                }
```

I use **`-std=c++14`**.

```
./concurrent.h:129:45: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'
                    thread_vector.push_back(std::thread(thread_do, 
                                            ^           ~~~~~~~~~~
```

However, I have no idea how to fix it. Tried to prepend **`&`** to the **`thread_do`**/appending **`<In, Out>`**, yet no to avail.

Comment: thread_do is both a template function and a class method. The constructor of std::thread will need to reflect that.

Comment: Woah, _way_ too much code. Where's the [MCVE] with which you've been debugging so far this month?

Comment: _"However, I have no idea how to fix it. Tried to prepend & to the thread_do/appending <In, Out>, yet no to avail."_ You could try reading the documentation, which really should have been your first step instead of wildly guessing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Next you suggest reading the entire standard?

Comment: Funkyfied the question a bit. If I can improve it, please tell me how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Comment: @coderodde: For now I would be content if you looked up the functions you use in a reputable reference. That's the minimum you should be doing on a daily basis, and it is definitely a step you must take before asking us to do it for you :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And yet, it would take me days to find out **`std::ref`**.

Comment: @coderodde: And think of all the other interesting things you'd learn while doing so. Looking through documentation for days is a _good_ thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate your function:

```
thread_vector.push_back(std::thread(thread_do<In, Out>,     // you need to instantiate your template function 
                                    std::ref(input_queue),  // pass parameters by ref 
                                    std::ref(process),      // - // -
                                    std::ref(output_vector))// - // -
                                    );
```

Answer (score 10):

This minimal, complete example (hint) shows you how to call a template member function in another thread.

```
#include <thread>

struct X
{

  template<class A, class B> void run(A a, B b)
  {
  }

  template<class A, class B>
  void run_with(A a, B b)
  {
    mythread = std::thread(&X::run<A, B>, this, a, b);
  }

  std::thread mythread;
};

int main()
{
  X x;
  x.run_with(10, 12);
  x.mythread.join();
}
```

Note that `std::thread`'s constructor is not able to auto-deduce template arguments. You have to be explicit.