# std::thread in c++ cant error when setting thread function

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I'm trying to use std::thread in c++ without success:

```
A.h

class A
{
   public:
      A();
      void MainThread();
      Init();

   private:
      std::thread currThread;
}

A.cpp

A::A()
{

}


void A::Init()
{
    currThread = std::thread(A::MainThread); 
    //currThread = std::thread(&MainThread);
}

void A::MainThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Just For Example...");
    }
}
```

I'm getting compilation error in the Init function when trying to create the thread with the MainFunction

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Pass this as argument.

Comment: Read up on member function pointers etc, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function. Also are you *sure* you need aseperate Init function and not just construct the thread in the constructor's initializer list? And should MainThread really be public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `MainThread()` method is not static, it will exist many times for different objects, so you need to indicate that you are referring to the method that belongs to `this` object (the object that you are calling `Init()` on).

There are many worrying things about your code (syntax error, infinite loop, etc.). Your example code (with the fix) should look something like this:

```
// A.hpp
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

#include <thread>

class A
{
   public:
      void Init();
      void MainThread();

   private:
      std::thread currThread;
};

#endif // A_HPP

// A.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "A.h"

void A::Init()
{
    this->currThread = std::thread(&A::MainThread, this);
}

void A::MainThread()
{
    //this loop will run forever
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Just For Example...";
    }
}
```

Comment: it still doesnt work.
the compiler does not like the code line: "this->currThread = std::thread(&A::MainThread);" I'm getting error: error: class "std::result_of<std::Mem_fn<void (A:::*)()> ()>" has no member "type"

Comment: Try this->currThread = std::thread(&A::MainThread, this);