# Why must I use address-of operator to get a pointer to a member function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, standards, language-design, pointer-to-member

```
struct A
{
    void f() {}
};

void f() {}

int main()
{
    auto p1 = &f;     // ok
    auto p2 = f;        // ok
    auto p3 = &A::f; // ok

    //
    // error : call to non-static member function
    // without an object argument
    //
    auto p4 = A::f; // Why not ok?
}
```

Why must I use address-of operator to get a pointer to a member function?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why would you need the address of a member function, and if you did have such a thing, what would you do with it?

Comment: e.g. `std::bind(&A::f, A());`

Comment: Also when passing a member function to `std::thread`.

Comment: You're playing with fire here. Why not use a [C++ lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) or a `static` wrapper function?

Comment: @PaulRooney Is a member function going to be happy if severed from any instance?

Comment: @tadman you have to pass the instance as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function.

Comment: @PaulRooney Ah, yeah, that's the ticket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
auto p1 = &f;     // ok
auto p2 = f;      // ok
```

The first is more or less the right thing. But because non-member functions have [implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to pointers, the `&` isn't necessary. C++ makes that conversion, same [applies](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/594ee85d91ca2dd8) to static member functions.

To quote from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer):

> An lvalue of function type `T` can be *implicitly converted* to a prvalue
>   pointer to that function. This does not apply to non-static member
>   functions because lvalues that refer to non-static member functions do
>   not exist.