# C++ Thread: Complicated function syntax

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

```
while (this->_data->window.isOpen()) // Main Loop
{
    this->_data->machine.ProcessStateChanges();
    std::thread t1 (this->_data->machine.ProcessStateChanges);
    std::thread t2 (dt = _clock.restart().asSeconds());
    std::thread t3 (this->_data->machine.GetActiveState()->HandleInput);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    this->_data->display.WindowEvent(this->_data->window);
    this->_data->machine.GetActiveState()->Update(dt);
    this->_data->machine.GetActiveState()->Draw(dt);
```

I get an error on `std::thread t1 (this->_data->machine.ProcessStateChanges);` and `std::thread t3 (this->_data->machine.GetActiveState()->HandleInput);` -- `error C3867: 'StateMachine::ProcessStateChanges': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member` And one for HandleInput. Normally this error just tells me that I forgot to put `()` on my functions, I know. But everything i've read on thread tells me that I skip it when taking the arguments for the thread. I've tried both ways.

These two functions are from a shared pointer to a struct called _data, which houses an object (my finite state machine) called machine. ProcessStateChanges checks to see if _data has made any requests to change the stack. Get active state is a function that returns a unique_ptr to the state in a stack on top. and HandleInput is a function in the state. None of these functions take arguments.

Now, when I run it without thread, it runs fine. I'd like it to run the functions concurrently, mostly to play with the thread concept, and trying to squeeze out a little more efficiency. However, I get an error when I try to pass the functions to a thread. I've tried with and without `()` attached.

I tried writing it like in the question page [start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function) : `std::thread t1(&StateMachine::ProcessStateChanges, this->_data);` And unless I'm missing something here, it doesn't work either. I get a huge page of errors starting with `error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found`

So my question is, what exactly am I passing as an argument when I create a thread if it's not just a function call? and what would the syntax be for something as complicated as a function call that comes from a Shared Pointer to a Struct object containing a Class object with a function that I want to call? or Even more complicated: a Shared pointer to a struct that has a class object that has a function that returns a reference to a unique pointer to a class object that has a function that I want to call?

Comment: better to show some more code to get clarity on your problem. probably signatures of functions which are throwing errors.

Comment: the only thing throwing errors is the thread... it all works if I run it without threads.

Comment: Try using `std::thread t1 (&ClassName::_data->machine.ProcessStateChanges);`. This should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I appreciate the help, none of the answers actually solved my problem. It was likely an issue with my description, perhaps.

However, I solved it by creating a functor:

`auto functor = [&](){this->_data->machine.ProcessStateChanges();};`

`std::thread t1(functor);`