# error: cannot call member function 'void Fortest::run()' without object|

Tags: c++

I am writing a really simple c++ program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

class Fortest{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Fortest(int a)
    {
        x=a;
    }
    void run(void)
    {
        cout<<"test sucesses!"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Fortest  hai(1);
    std::thread  t;

    t=std::thread(std::ref(hai),&Fortest::run());
    t.join();

    cout<<"program ends"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And I am constantly getting the error "cannot call a member function without an object". Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Answer (score 2):

You have *two* problems:

The first is that you *call* the thread function, passing a pointer to the value it returns. You should pass a pointer to the *function*.

The second problem is that you pass the [`std::thread` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) arguments in the wrong order. The pointer to the function is the *first* argument, and the object to call it on is the *second* (which is the first argument to the function).

I.e. it should be something like

```
t = std::thread(&Fortest::run, &hai);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling it the wrong way

Try:

```
Fortest  hai(1);
std::thread  t;

t=std::thread(&Fortest::run, std::ref(hai));
t.join();
```

or do so by `t=std::thread(&Fortest::run, &hai);` 
Check the arguments on [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe6feeb0a036f2af)