# Execute one method in another thread

Tags: c++

I want to execute `DisplayWriters` in another thread. Unfortunelly I am getting erorr: `Invalid use of non static member function` This is the code:

```
 void Chat::Init() {
    //some code

    thread writersThread(Chat::DisplayWriters);
}

void Chat::DisplayWriters() {
    for (auto &v : writers) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I cant really do `DisplayWriters` static, because it is using `writers` list which is in `Chat` class. So what can I do with that?

Comment: Non-static member functions needs to be called on a specific object. Try passing e.g. `this` as the second argument to the `std::thread` constructor.

Comment: A non-static member function needs to be invoked on an object of `Chat` type. Where is the thread supposed to get this object from? Also, a pointer to member **must** be formed with `&`

Comment: Also note that you should [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) threads you create (unless you [detach](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) them) to avoid a resource leak.

Comment: try `thread writersThread(&Chat::DisplayWriters, this);` (for using the same object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude or even std::terminate being called in the case of std::thread!

Comment: @水飲み鳥 Is the `&` needed?

Comment: @GauravSehgal it is if the member function is non-`static`.

Comment: If you create a thread and after that, the scope of it is going to be finished, the destructor of it is called in which the join function is called. That is, this function does not run async-only on another thread-.

Comment: @mahdi_12167 that's `std::future`. `std::thread` [terminates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread) if you let it die before joining.

Answer (score -1):

If really you want to run the DisplayFunction asynchrony, you should do something such this.

```
class Chat {
    thread* writersThread = nullptr;
void Init() {
    //some code
    writersThread = new thread(&Chat::DisplayWriters, *this);
}

void DisplayWriters() {
    for (auto &v : writers) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
~Chat() {
    if(writersThread) {
        writersThread->join();
        delete writersThread;
    }
}
};
```

Comment: @Quentin: thread is not copyable and must be instantiated once. besides, after losing the scope-Init function- its join function would be called.

Comment: But your class still isn't copyable (in fact, it is, which will lead to a nasty double-delete). `writersThread = std::thread{&Chat::DisplayWriters, *this}` would work just fine after a default initialization. I'm not sure what you mean with that `join()` part -- you could still `join()` inside the destructor just as well.

Comment: `writersThread = std::thread{&Chat::DisplayWriters, *this}` could be run in function which is not constructor?

Comment: Yes, of course. `std::sthread` is not copyable, but it is movable :)

Comment: I would not have copyable class, I would set the not copyable thread which is not local.