# Call one Member function from another member function using thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, class

I am new in threading and classes, and trying to create a class. I have two member function in which one call the other using thread.

```
    bool CSocket::StartCamera()
{
    bool m_SendFlag;
    m_SocketIn = socketInitialize(m_CameraIP, m_CameraPort);
    if (m_SocketIn == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return false;
    m_SendFlag = sendCommand(m_SocketIn);
    if (!m_SendFlag)
        return false;
    std::thread acquiringThread(&CSocket::callReceiveFxn, m_SocketIn);
    acquiringThread.join();
}
```

and other member function is

```
 void CSocket::callReceiveFxn(SOCKET socket)
{
    unsigned char *m_frameBuffer = NULL;
    while (true)
    {
        m_frameBuffer = receivePacket(socket);
        m_ImageQ.Enqueue(m_frameBuffer, MAX_BYTE_PER_FRAME);
    }
}
```

So my `StartCamera` function call the `callReceiveFxn` using thread.
But at `std::thread acquiringThread(&CSocket::callReceiveFxn, m_SocketIn);` error occur that says
Error   3   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

So can anyone tell me why this error comes and please tell the solution for that

Comment: You create a thread only to immediately wait for it to finish. The thread also happens to never return. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: The error is telling you `CSocket::callReceiveFxn` is not a function taking one argument. It is a _member_ function, and they're different.

Comment: @PasserBy because it continuously take image frame I will use IPC later to stop the thread

Comment: so how to call that member function using thread

Comment: Possible dupe of ["Start thread with member function
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function).

Comment: Aside: Why do you use the `m_` prefix for *some* local variables? That's *actively misleading* use of Hungarian notation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a value for the (implicit) `this` parameter of `callReceiveFxn`.

You also wait for the thread to finish before returning, the thread is superfluous. Perhaps you want the thread to continue after `StartCamera` finishes?

You fail to return a value at the end of the function.

I don't like the hungarian notation for members, but even worse is using it for locals.

```
bool CSocket::StartCamera()
{
    m_SocketIn = socketInitialize(m_CameraIP, m_CameraPort);
    if (m_SocketIn == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return false;
    if (!sendCommand(m_SocketIn))
        return false;
    std::thread(&CSocket::callReceiveFxn, this, m_SocketIn).detach();
    return true;
}
```

Note that `callReceiveFxn` might not need a parameter, it can access `m_SocketIn`

Comment: Sir the StartCamera() is calling from main function if I use detach then both main and callReceiveFxn work concurrently

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with member functions, as the error is stating. But since you're using `std::thread`, I'm certain you're using at least C++11. Therefore, you have access to lambdas.

You can simply call the member in a lambda and pass that lambda to the constructor of `std::thread`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass class instance pointer:

```
std::thread acquiringThread(&CSocket::callReceiveFxn, this, m_SocketIn);
```