# Compilation error while using class member function for std::thread with unique pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, stdthread

I am new to C++, I need to use class object' member function as a thread function, and the object is used in application class and object cannot be shared so it is a unique pointer. When I am trying to create the thread, I am getting the compilation error.

I cannot copy the code as is so just created a sample code snippet.

`DerivedType`<-`Base3Type`<-`Base2Type`<-`Base1Type` - `DerivedType` is declared as private in application class

```
class AppClass
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<DerivedType> transport;
public:

}

AppClass::Open()
{

    transport= std::make_unique<DerivedType>(client, logger);

    std::thread receive(&DerivedType::receive, &transport, flag, 1000);//flag and 100 are arguments to DerivedType::receive function.
}
```

I am getting the following compilation error

```
/usr/include/c++/5.2.1/functional:634:20: **error: pointer to member type ‘void (Base1Type::Base2Type::Base3Type::DerivedType::)(std::shared_ptr<bool>, const short unsigned int&)’ incompatible with object type ‘std::unique_ptr<Base1Type::Base2Type::Base3Type::DerivedType>’**
  { return ((*__ptr).*_M_pmf)(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
                    ^

/usr/include/c++/5.2.1/functional:634:60: **error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]**
  { return ((*__ptr).*_M_pmf)(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Please let me know how to get it compiled and execute without crash. Thank you.

Comment: please see the question in detail, it is not a direct straight forward member function usage issue, my issue involves unique pointer which makes it difficult to debug

Comment: `&DerivedType::receive` seems to expect a `std::shared_ptr`. Is that what you are trying to pass `transport` to? Is `receive` static? Please share a [MCVE], it would answer these questions. Note that `transport` is being passed by copy but isn't copyable.

Comment: yes 'flag' is std::shared_ptr and receive is not a static function. Sorry I missed to mention &transport, which I edited now.

Comment: Then the [previously posted duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function) is relevant. You need to pass some form of instance to call a member function. `&transport` is a pointer to a `unique_ptr` and a step in the wrong direction. The rest of my previous concerns still stand. You can't copy a `std::unique_ptr` so change `receive` and pass it by reference (don't forget `std::ref`) or store transport in a `std::shared_ptr`. Again, please take the time to write a [MCVE] so that this question can be answered properly and we can skip the back and forth.

Comment: thanks @Francois, sorry i didn't have time to get minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call member function as body of thread so you need to pass pointer to `DerivedType` object (use `unique_ptr::get` method), not pointer to `unique_ptr`, write

```
std::thread receive(&DerivedType::receive, transport.get(), flag, 1000);//
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> and execute without crash.

now your code will be aborted by `terminate` function while calling destructor of thread at the end of `Open` method because your `thread` is in joinable state. So you need to choose

1. call `join` on `receive` thread object, then you wait in `Open` method (it doesn't make sense)
2. call `detach` on `receive` object but then you must ensure that `transport` object will not be destroyed before task started in `receive` thread ends.

Comment: thank you so much, its working with detach option

Comment: You can also make thread receive as member data of app class and then you can call join on receive in somewhere in your code - it is another solution instead of calling detach.

Comment: @enthu Think really hard before using `detach`. After you `detach` you no longer have any control over the thread. The most significant downside is the program can now exit before the thread does and you have no way to stop it from happening.

Comment: @enthu A proper solution usually doesn't need to use `detach`. It's more likely that it's a red flag that there is a problem with your design which will eventually become apparent.

Comment: yes i got rid of detach, used thread receive member of app class, thank you