# C++ "error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of< ... >"

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, grpc

I am trying to compile a gRPC server, but I get the error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/mutex:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/condition_variable:39,
                 from /home/msl/maum/include/grpc++/server.h:22,
                 from wavenet_server.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void* (WavenetServiceImpl::*)(void*)>(void**)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/thread:137:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void* (WavenetServiceImpl::*)(void*); _Args = {void* (&)[2]}]’
wavenet_server.cc:317:73:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void* (WavenetServiceImpl::*)(void*)>(void**)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void* (WavenetServiceImpl::*)(void*)>(void**)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

My guess is this line in `wavenet_server.cc`:

`std::thread t(&WavenetServiceImpl::threadWavenetInfer, thread_args);`

is introducing ambiguity ( the compiler does not know if this is a function decloration or an expression, maybe? )

So I tried to replace the line with:

`std::thread t{&WavenetServiceImpl::threadWavenetInfer, thread_args};`

but that did not work either

Is this the correct source of the problem? and how may I fix it? If that line is not the problem, then please let me know ( The source code is too long to paste, and I cannot tell which line is the problem because I cannot understand the error message, but I will try my best ).

Comment: What are `WavenetServiceImpl::threadWavenetInfer` and `thread_args`? Are you sure the former can be called with the latter (if it's a class method, remember that it needs `this` ptr, you may have better luck with lambdas).

Comment: @DanM. The former is a class function and the latter is void**.  Do you think this can be a problem?

Comment: Member functions have an implicit `this` as a first argument. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function and check if it helps. Your question lacks [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to answer with more certainty.

Comment: Where did you get your compiler? What's your distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a newer GCC version if you want to use C++11 features such as `std::result_of`.  GCC 4.8 has only very experimental C++11 support.  It is generally recommended to use it only in C++98 mode.

If you want to use C++11 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, you should get a recent version of Red Hat Developer Toolset:

- [Red Hat Developer Toolset](https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/overview/)

For CentOS, [DTS is available through the Software Collections site](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/).

Please keep in mind that due to the way DTS works, you need to compile all C++11 code with DTS, so you cannot use a precompiled gRPC library.

Comment: I am using: g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) and on compile time, I provide -std=c++11 flag. Do you suggest I update my GCC? I am afraid to use c++98 because in the gRPC demo provided by google, they used c++11. Also, I have a cuda device code I compiled with c++11.

Comment: You can use DTS. I added a few links.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to download it from the second link. However, I am using my company’s server, so I must not update any default compiler or change environment variable. Is there a way to preserve all the default setting and the old compiler, and only use the newest version when I set the environment variable explicitly?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how DTS works. Everything stays as it is until you use `scl enable devtoolset-7`, and then the new `g++` command is only activated for the program you run.