# Start thread with member function (with inheritance)

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance

So my problem starts pretty much like this question:
[Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

I have some class Foo, that looks like this:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    int y;
    thread t;

    void set(int x){
       y = x;
    }

    void plan(int x){
        thread = std::thread ([&]{
        set(x);
    });

    void get(){
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();
    }
};
```

Other answers also suggest:

```cpp
    void plan(int x){
        thread = std::thread(&Foo::set, this, x);
    };
```

Now, I want to use `Foo` as a base class for various child class with overloaded `set()` functions, for exemple:

```cpp
struct Bar: public Foo
{
    void set(int x){
       y = x*2;
    }
}
```

My problem is that if done that way, `Bar::plan()` result in `Foo::set()` being runned in the new thread instead of `Bar::set` as expected.

Is there another solution than having to write again the `plan()` method in every child class of `Foo`?

Comment: Don't capture `x` by reference, as its lifetime might be shorter than thread.

Comment: What is  " y = x**2; " ?

Comment: @2785528 : a typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might simply make `set` `virtual`:

```
struct Foo
{
    // ...
    virtual void set(int x);
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
    void set(int x) override;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just mark `set` as `virtual` and use the lambda version, being careful to capture everything by value, as the `plan` invocation may (and probably will) return before the thread actually start to run.

```
struct Foo
{
    int y;
    thread t;

    virtual void set(int x){
       y = x;
    }

    void plan(int x){
        t = std::thread ([this, x]{
            this->set(x);
        });
    }

    void get(){
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();
    }
};
```

this will call the correct `set` version even when `plan` is invoked in a derived class.

Comment: I think it is not necessary to use lambda in plan(). `std::bind` should do the job here.

Comment: @KunalPuri: why risk? Lambdas rules are simpler and clearer, and it's immediately clear what they do. `std::bind` and its rotten kin? Not much. I wouldn't bet anything over whether it does the right thing (whatever it is) or not in regard to virtual methods, and most programmers I know, me included, [would have to look it up on a reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) - if you can understand what happens it behind the forest of `std::decay::whatever`. Personally I wasted 30 seconds looking for details about `virtual` and then gave up.

Comment: It was that simple. I'm not sure however how to use std::bind here though? edit: nevermind.

Comment: @KunalPuri Wrong way round. It is not necessary to use `std::bind` in `plan()` because a lambda will do the job here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually, Both are not required in this case. See my answer.

Comment: @KunalPuri As was covered in comments under your answer a few hours ago, that solution is basically `std::bind`

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer has been accepted already, Here is a way to do the same using std::bind.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    int y;
    thread t;

    virtual void set(int x){
       y = x;
    }

    void plan(int x){
        t = std::thread (std::bind(&Foo::set, this, x));
    }

    void get(){
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();
    }
};

struct Bar: public Foo
{
    void set(int x){
        cout << "Called" << endl;
       y = x*2;
    }
};

int main() {
    Bar b;
    b.plan(2);
    b.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Also, Without using lambda, you could have done this also:

```
void plan(int x){
    t = std::thread (&Foo::set, this, x);
}
```

Comment: `std::bind` here just adds yet another wrapping layer for what is already available through the `std::thread` constructor (both mostly just defer the hard lifting to the `std::invoke` machinery)

Comment: Thank you for showing how to use std::bind in that context. However your solution without lambda gave me: "error: cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function".

Comment: `&this->set` should be `&Foo::set`.

Comment: For me, `&this->set` is working. @Jarod42 `&Foo::set` could be used also. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @KunalPuri: `&this->set` is invalid: [Demo for bind](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2849bcc0527b9050) and [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6ca0f4355f0b756)

Comment: I agree with your point @MatteoItalia. That's why I included both. Because OP wanted to know how to use `std::bind` in this case.

Comment: @Jarod42 I am using `i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe` and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think ISO C++ forbids it. I don't know how it is working on `i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe` 7.1.0.