# How to create a thread inside a class?

Tags: c++

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        friend void function(MyClass& mc)
        {
            std::cout << "Friend function from thread" << std::endl;
        }    
        void init()
        {
            thr = std::thread(function, this);
            thr.join();
        }

    private:
        std::thread thr;

};

  int main()
   {
    std::cout << "This is main function" << std::endl;
    MyClass nc;
    nc.init();

    return 0;
   }
```

> Error C2065 'function': undeclared identifier

How to create thread inside a class not using any static function?

Comment: Why are you not doing init in your constructor? I think you need to initialize thread directly in your constructor for it to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Comment: You forgot ro dereference `this`, but there seem to be more errors.

Comment: @AlanBirtles How is this a duplicate? Here we have a friend definition, which creates non-member functions.

Comment: @styphNate `std::thread` is not copiable, but movable. You can assign an rvalue at any time to a thread in any state (see [operator=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator=)).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not a true duplicate - but still showing a possible way to avoid *static* functions...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I hadn't noticed the friend function, I guess the OP only did that because they didn't know how to call a member function from a `std::thread`, I can't see why else you'd try to declare a friend function for a class inside a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well @mkaes beat me to the answer, but I had slightly modified your `function()` to accept a pointer to the class and not a reference.

- You cannot access a friend function inside a class like you can access other member functions.

  1. The problem was that your friend function had no global declaration even though, you were declaring it as a friend function in the class.
  2. So we define the function outside the class and leave a friend declaration inside.
  3. Now since the `function()` doesn't know about the class `MyClass`, we have to forward declare the `MyClass` class also.

## code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class MyClass;

void function(MyClass* mc)
{
    std::cout << "Friend function from thread" << std::endl;
}

class MyClass
{
public:
    void init()
    {
       thr = std::thread(function, this);
       thr.join();
        // function(this);
    }
    friend void function(MyClass* mc);
private:
    std::thread thr;

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is main function" << std::endl;
    MyClass nc;
    nc.init();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> This is main function 
>   Friend function from thread

**EDIT:**

As per the discussion in the comments, my first code posted here had the problem that you could not call a member function or access a member variable inside the friend `function()`, since the class was defined afterwards. To address that here is the alternative below. But anyways, @mkaes has already answered it in this way from the beginning.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class MyClass;
void function(MyClass* mc);

class MyClass
{
public:
    void init()
    {
       thr = std::thread(function, this);
       thr.join();
        // function(this);
    }
    friend void function(MyClass* mc)
    {
        std::cout << "Friend function from thread" << std::endl;
        mc->test();
    }
    int test(){}
private:
    std::thread thr;

};



int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is main function" << std::endl;
    MyClass nc;
    nc.init();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *'And you cannot access a friend function inside a class like you can access other member functions.'* - the 'why' would be the most interesting point about. Any reference to the standard?

Comment: @Aconcagua, my point was **NOT like other member functions** *(other than that you can do it, like in the above code, for example `:)` )*. I don't have a reference to the standard, but I guess that it has something to do with the *friend* function no relationship to *this*, like static functions.

Comment: Hm, I recall something like inlined member functions being compiled as if being defined right after the class - so that they can see the complete class definition and access members no matter if declared after or before the function. Suppose the same applies for the inline friends as well, apparently (unfortunately) placing the definition after the member definitions (instead of e. g. in between class and members)...

Comment: Ah ok. Good to know. Thanks for sharing that @Aconcagua. `:)`

Comment: Thank's for your reply. can you please tell me if i can call member function inside thread then how? I am using VS2017 as IDE

Comment: @pronobroy, yes, you can. But for that the code needs to be changed a bit. The function definition would have to moved to after the class definition *(or even inside the class)*. And the place where the function has been defined, needs to be replaced with the function declaration.

Comment: @pronobroy, I edited my answer. But as you can see mkaes, has already answered this correctly from the beginning.

Comment: @pronobroy, best to keep `class definition` in a `header file` (containing the declarations only *hopefully*) and `class implementation` in separate `source file`, so that you don't bump into such problems anyways.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know why the lookup of your friend function does not work in this context, maybe someone else knows.
But the fastest way to archive what you want is either a lamdba or declare your function.
E.g.

```
class MyClass;
void function(MyClass& mc);
class MyClass
{
public:
    friend void function(MyClass& mc)
    ...
    void init()
    {
        // either do this
        thr = std::thread([this](){function(*this);});
        // or this note the std::ref. You are passing a reference. Otherwise there will be a copy
        thr = std::thread(&function, std::ref(*this));
        thr.join();
    }

private:
    std::thread thr;

};
....
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to pass a pointer by value, instead of a `std::ref` to a dereferenced pointer.

Comment: @super ["compiler says no"](https://godbolt.org/z/nZMZHA). or how did you mean it?

Comment: @super I don't think so. The `function` accepts a reference and not a pointer. So passing the pointer by value won't work here. Another solution would be to change `function` to accept a `MyClass*` then the pointer by value would be fine.

Comment: Right, missed the whole friend function. Too early.