# Why "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member" using thread within a CTOR?

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, visual-c++

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct PickRandomFile {
    PickRandomFile() {
        std::thread t1(taskScanPaths);
    }

    inline void taskScanPaths() {
        // my task
    }
};

int main() {
    PickRandomFile pickRandomFile;

    return 0;
}
```

`msvc` says *PickRandomFile::taskScanPaths': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member ThreadTrigger*

What's wrong? I usually do it in `gcc`.

Comment: You're looking for `std::thread t1(&PickRandomFile::taskScanPaths, this);`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function

Comment: That's not required in gcc. Why?

Comment: Which gcc version does compile this code? All I've tried give me an error `error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void PickRandomFile::taskScanPaths()'` (bit less descriptive in earlier versions). [online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zvW0ssYTe8LH9GZu)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: `gcc.exe (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.1.0`

Comment: fails for all for me: https://godbolt.org/z/zocZja

Comment: Not sure, it works fine with that version on other projects :P

Comment: @markzzz In those other projects, are you using class functions or free functions?

Comment: @markzzz As the message says: It's **non-standard syntax**, i.e. something that msvc/gcc can graciously allow that would be invalid according to the C++ standard. The reasons/conditions when it allows this (or even prints a warning/errors out) are probably dependent on your compiler version and build flags (assuming that this very same code works in other circumstances).

Comment: @NathanOliver as the code above: a "inline void" function within a class (a struct=. Would you call it free?

Comment: @markzzz No.  A free function is a function at global or namespace scope.  Making it inline doesn't do anything here since member functions that are defined inside a class are implicitly inline.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know :) Still it doesn't prompt nothing. I can live with it anyway, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Free functions "decay to pointers" (similar to arrays) so

```
std::thread t1(taskScanPaths);
```

would have been ok if `taskScanPaths` was a free function and it would have same effect as

```
std::thread t1(&taskScanPaths);
```

However, for class member function you need the address-of to get a pointer to the member function (and you need to specify the class), as in

```
std::thread t1(&PickRandomFile::taskScanPaths,this);
```

Also note that you need to pass a object/pointer to an instance so the thread can actually call the method.

Some relevant quotes from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer):

> **Pointer to member functions**
>
> A pointer to non-static member function f which is a member of class C
>   can be initialized with the expression &C::f exactly. Expressions such
>   as &(C::f) **or &f inside C's member function do not form pointers to
>   member functions**.

It does not explicitly mention `f`, but as `&f` does not form a pointer to member function, it is kinda safe to assume `f` also does not form a pointer to member function.

On the other hand:

> **Pointers to functions**
>
> A pointer to function can be initialized with an address of a
>   non-member function or a static member function. **Because of the
>   function-to-pointer implicit conversion, the address-of operator is
>   optional:**

Comment: don't forget you need a object/pointer of the class type as the second parameter if it is a non-static function.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks fixed. Anyhow I didnt pay attention to who is the asker and it seems that focus is more on "why gcc allowed it", I guess its comes as non-standard extension

Comment: AFAIK it can't ever work.  GCC can't know which object to call the function on.  My guess is the OP had free functions in the other examples.

Comment: @NathanOliver reading a bit I also could convince myself of the same, will add a bit more