# Pass calling method with variable and returning object to <thread>

Tags: c++

```
FirstStructure first = {};
SecondStructure second = {};
char buffer[1024] = {};

second.init(); // set some attributes

int fd = second.get();

// L9: first = second.getMore(fd);

// L11: std::thread t1(&SecondStructure::getMore, &first, fd);

// printf("%d\n", first.firstAtr);
// printf("%d\n", first.secAtr);
```

I'd like to execute `L9` with `thread`.

On the `L11` is some of my trying, it doesn't work, so feel free to ignore it.

Thanks for some help!

Comment: You need to post the signature of the `getMore` function, you seem to be calling it differently on L9 and L11.

Comment: Will it work if you add `t1.join()` after L11? Upd: maybe you meant `second` on L11, like `std::thread t1(&SecondStructure::getMore, &second, fd);`?

Comment: @nick I am a bit confused, could you give me a little example or more hints?

Comment: @user3365922 Maybe, but how can I store the output to `first`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the signature for this function `SecondStructure::getMore` i.e. something like `void SecondStructure::getMore(FirstStructure*, int) {...}` But you should try `t1.join()` first, that is a much better idea.

Comment: I thought it is clear from `L9`, I am sorry. It looks like `int SecondStructure::getMore(int fd)`.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function).

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to pass a lambda to your thread. Something like

```
std::thread t1([&](){ first = second.getMore(fd); });
```

Make sure you join the thread at some appropriate time later.