# Can't start C++ std::thread with callable as argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates

I would like to have the following class setup in a program:

- A class that implements a buffer. This buffer, when full, would spawn a thread that makes a callback to handle what to do with the full buffer.
- A class that includes a buffer object. Implements the callback function.

I'm having some trouble spawning the std::thread that runs the callback. It seems like I'm getting its parameters wrong, but I can't figure it out.

The minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <thread>

class MyClass;

class CallbackClass
{
    public:

        void (MyClass::*callback)();
        std::thread a_thread;

        void setCallback(void (MyClass::*cb)())
        {
            callback = cb;
        }

        void writeCall()
        {
            a_thread = std::thread(callback); // error here
        }
};

class MyClass
{
    public:

        CallbackClass callbackobject;

        MyClass()
        {
            callbackobject.setCallback(&MyClass::bufferWriter);
        }

        void bufferWriter(){}
};

int main(){}
```

The compiler error I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (MyClass::*)()> >::_M_invoke(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (MyClass::*)()> >::_Indices)’
  operator()()
```

on this line:

```
a_thread = std::thread(callback); // error here
```

Comment: Was this error attached to any particular line of code?

Comment: @Useless Yes, I've marked it with a comment.

Comment: "callback" is not a callable object. "callback" is a class method. How do you expect `std::thread` to know which object's callback method to invoke? That's your problem. `callback` needs a `Base<T>` object whose method it will invoke.

Comment: I've highlighted it a bit for future viewers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Comment: Unrelated: This code generates lots of warnings. Some may be important, like `‘class Base<int>’ has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor`. You should turn on more warnings when compiling and try to fix them all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, thanks. That problem is related to stripping too much code for the minimal reproducible example, but I actually have a virtual destructor in Base.

Comment: I actually answered a similar question yesterday, and could probably answer this one as well, but this is not a "minimal reproducible example", unlike what you state. Shorten it to ~5 lines, should help you find the issue yourself (probably https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You mean that I should store a reference to a Base<T> object as a CallbackBuffer member so I can later invoke Base<T>::bufferWriter? Wouldn't that create a circular dependence?

Comment: @NadavS I know it's too much code, but believe me, I've tried to reproduce the error with less, but as soon as I remove a couple more things, it starts compiling even with the error line intact. I wrote the example from scratch, not stripping the actual code, as you may think.

Comment: The only thing I think is that keyword `template` is not necessary to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @NadavS Thank you. I've simplified a little more.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik -- `callback` **is** a callable object. A callable type is either a function object type or a pointer to member (and, yes, "pointer to member" includes pointers to member data), and a callable object is an object of a callable type. [func.def] Nevertheless, the problem is, as you say, that for a pointer-to-member the next argument has to be a pointer or reference to an object that the pointer-to-member can be applied to.

Comment: What "circular dependence" are you referring to? C++ is not Java.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok, the problem seems solved by storing a pointer to a Base object. Would you like to create an answer so I can vote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void (MyClass::*callback)();
```

This is a pointer to a class method.

```
a_thread = std::thread(callback);
```

A class method is not a function that can be called by itself. The class method requires an object for which it gets invoked. You need to store, or obtain a pointer to a `MyClass` object, from somewhere. For example, you can pass a 2nd parameter to `setCallback:

```
void setCallback(void (MyClass::*cb)(), MyClass *ptr)
```

and then stash it away, somewhere, then use it to invoke the class method. Typically, this would be something like:

```
a_thread = std::thread(callback, ptr);
```