# How to call thread with a public member function from another class as argument

Tags: c++, multithreading

I already checked [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function) and similar posts, and followed the instructions, but I get this error message:

> 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found

SerialPort.h

```
#include <array>
#include <string>

class AudioClass
{
public:
    void playAudio(std::array<std::string, 11> turretDetectionWavFiles, std::array<std::string, 6> turretActivationWavFiles,
        std::array<std::string, 4> turretSearchingWavFiles, std::array<std::string, 16> turretPowerDownWavFiles, std::array<std::string, 3> turretAttackWavFiles, std::array<std::string, 11> turretMovedWavFiles,
        std::array<std::string, 12> turretDie);
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include "SerialPort.h"

std::array<std::string, 11> turretDetectionWavFiles{ "alarm.wav", "alert.wav",  "active.wav", "turret_active_1.wav", "turret_active_2.wav", "turret_active_3.wav", "turret_active_4.wav", "turret_active_5.wav",
                                          "turret_active_6.wav", "turret_active_7.wav", "turret_active_8.wav" };
std::array<std::string, 6> turretActivationWavFiles{ "turret_deploy_1.wav", "turret_deploy_2.wav", "turret_deploy_3.wav", "turret_deploy_4.wav", "turret_deploy_5.wav",
                                           "turret_deploy_6.wav" };
std::array<std::string, 4> turretSearchingWavFiles{ "turret_search_1.wav", "turret_search_2.wav", "turret_search_3.wav", "turret_search_4.wav" };

std::array<std::string, 16> turretPowerDownWavFiles{ "turret_disabled_1.wav", "turret_disabled_2.wav", "turret_disabled_3.wav", "turret_disabled_4.wav", "turret_disabled_5.wav",
                                           "turret_disabled_6.wav", "turret_disabled_7.wav", "turret_disabled_8.wav", "turret_retire_1.wav", "turret_retire_2.wav",
                                           "turret_retire_3.wav", "turret_retire_4.wav", "turret_retire_5.wav", "turret_retire_6.wav", "turret_retire_7.wav", "retract.wav" };

std::array<std::string, 3> turretAttackWavFiles{ "turret_fire_4x_01.wav", "turret_fire_4x_02.wav", "turret_fire_4x_03.wav" };

std::array<std::string, 11> turretMovedWavFiles{ "turretlaunched10.wav", "turret_pickup_1.wav", "turret_pickup_2.wav", "turret_pickup_3.wav", "turret_pickup_4.wav", "turret_pickup_5.wav",
                                      "turret_pickup_6.wav", "turret_pickup_7.wav", "turret_pickup_8.wav", "turret_pickup_9.wav", "turret_pickup_10.wav" };

std::array<std::string, 12> turretDie{ "sp_sabotage_factory_good_fail01.wav", "sp_sabotage_factory_good_fail04.wav", "sp_sabotage_factory_good_fail06.wav",
                            "sp_sabotage_factory_good_fail05.wav", "sp_sabotage_factory_good_fail07.wav", "turret_tipped_1", "turret_tipped_2", "turret_tipped_3",
                            "turret_tipped_4", "turret_tipped_5", "turret_tipped_6", "die.wav" }; 


void AudioClass::playAudio(std::array<std::string, 11> turretDetectionWavFiles, std::array<std::string, 6> turretActivationWavFiles,
    std::array<std::string, 4> turretSearchingWavFiles, std::array<std::string, 16> turretPowerDownWavFiles, std::array<std::string, 3> turretAttackWavFiles, std::array<std::string, 11> turretMovedWavFiles,
    std::array<std::string, 12> turretDie)
{
    //do something
}

void exampleReceiveData()
{
    std::thread t(AudioClass::playAudio, (turretDetectionWavFiles, turretActivationWavFiles, turretSearchingWavFiles, turretPowerDownWavFiles, turretAttackWavFiles, turretMovedWavFiles, turretDie));
}

int main()
{
    exampleReceiveData();
}
```

I also tried this way, and got the same error:

```
std::thread t(&AudioClass::playAudio, AudioClass());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *this* pointer needs to be passed as the 1st argument:

```
void exampleReceiveData(void)
{
    AudioClass ac;    
    std::thread t(&AudioClass::playAudio, &ac, turretDetectionWavFiles, 
                  turretActivationWavFiles, turretSearchingWavFiles, 
                  turretPowerDownWavFiles, turretAttackWavFiles, 
                  turretMovedWavFiles, turretDie);
    t.join();
}
```